# Checking null and string.Empty in C#

Tags: c#, .net

This might sound like a noob question, but are:

```
string var;
if (var == null)
```

and

```
string var;
if (var == string.Empty)
```

The same?

> #### **Duplicate**
>
> [What's the Difference between String.Empty and Null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and) and [In C#, should I use String.Empty or Null?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)

Comment: Duplicate. I've seen this question before. Sigh, now I have to dive through the depths of SO to find it.

Comment: -1 to Gortok (in theory)... Find the dupe before you vote to close!

Comment: Found it, Jon B: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Comment: OK, Gortok - +1 to you (to close, that is).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

@Jay is correct, they are not the same.  `String.IsNullOrEmpty()` is a convenient method to check for both null and "".

Answer (score 19):

No, they are not the same.

`string.Empty` is the same as `""`, which is an actual object: a string of 0 length.  `null` means there is no object.

Answer (score 6):

they are not the same, the implementation of String.IsNullOrEmpty(string) in mscorlib demonstrate it:

```
public static bool IsNullOrEmpty(string value)
{
    if (value != null)
    {
        return (value.Length == 0);
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: sorry, I'm a New User at StackOverflow.com

Comment: +1 for reminding people to go to the source of the code for learning purposes

Answer (score 3):

No, they are not. First one checks if the variable has been initialized or if it was set to "null" later. Second one checks if the value of the variable is "" (empty).
However, you shouldn't use either. You should use string.IsNullOrEmpty(var) instead.

Answer (score 0):

But sometimes you want to know if the string is `NULL` and it does not matter that its empty (in a OO design). For example you have a method and it will return `NULL` or a `string.` you do this because null means the operation failed and an empty string means there is no result.

In some cases you want to know if it failed or if it has no result prior to take any further actions in other objects.