# How to replace a char in string with an Empty character in C#.NET

Tags: c#

I have a string like this:

```
string val = "123-12-1234";
```

How can I replace the dashes using an empty string in C#.

I mean `val.Replace(char oldChar, newChar);`

What needs to go in `oldChar` and `newChar`.

Comment: Why the downvote? It may be a simple question to answer but that does not make it wrong surely? New users may become disheartened quite quickly...

Comment: Agree w/ Peter Kelly -- upvoting

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to replace occurrences of "-" with an empty string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/894905/how-to-replace-occurrences-of-with-an-empty-string)

Comment: Somebody mind explaining why this got closed as *too localized* ?

Comment: Duplicate, yes, downvote, no, too localized, no.

Comment: Yeah, "too localized" is wrong.  But i'm not voting to reopen; i'm saving my vote to close it as a duplicate if it manages to get reopened.  Nothing personal.  :)

Answer (score 172, accepted):

You can use a different overload of `Replace()` that takes string.

```
val = val.Replace("-", string.Empty)
```

Comment: +1 for mentioning that the alternative method is an "overload"

Comment: Try replacing the \0 character using the above overload and it will not work! The \0 character will not be replaced. This is especially true when working with string data received from Snmp devices

Comment: The reason for why char to char replacement overload will not work here - [Why is there no Char.Empty like String.Empty?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3670505/465053)

Comment: I had a variable in place of the "-" above and used charToReplace.ToString() in its place.

Comment: Remember when using `Replace`, the `oldValue` type must be the same as `newValue`. Ex. `Replace(';',string.Empty.ToCharArray()[0])` or `Replace(";", "")` also works.

Answer (score 72):

Since the other answers here, even though correct, do not explicitly address your initial doubts, I'll do it.

If you call `string.Replace(char oldChar, char newChar)` it will replace the occurrences of a character with another character. It is a one-for-one replacement. Because of this the length of the resulting string will be the same.

What you want is to *remove* the dashes, which, obviously, is not the same thing as replacing them with another character. You cannot replace it by "no character" because 1 character is always 1 character. That's why you need to use the overload that takes strings: strings can have different lengths. If you replace a string of length 1, with a string of length 0, the effect is that the dashes are gone, replaced by "nothing".

Comment: Thanks for giving a detailed explanation.

Comment: After all that, you didn't demonstrate.  :P  Oh well.  +1 anyway for the explanation

Comment: You can find more information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3670660/3136474).

Answer (score 9):

```
val.Replace("-", "");
```

[MSDN Source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk49wtc1.aspx)

Answer (score 8):

This seems too simple, but:

```
val.Replace("-","");
```

Answer (score 6):

```
string val = "123-12-1234";

val = val.Replace("-", ""); // result: 123121234
```

Answer (score 5):

If you want to replace a char in a string with an empty char that means you want to remove that char from a string, read the answer of R. Martinho Fernandes.

Here is an exemple of how to remove a char from a string (replace with an "Empty char"):

```
    public static string RemoveCharFromString(string input, char charItem)
    {
        int indexOfChar = input.IndexOf(charItem);
        if (indexOfChar >= 0)
        {
            input = input.Remove(indexOfChar, 1);
        }
        return input;
    }
```

or this version that removes all recurrences of a char in a string :

```
    public static string RemoveCharFromString(string input, char charItem)
    {
        int indexOfChar = input.IndexOf(charItem);
        if (indexOfChar < 0)
        {
            return input;
        }
        return RemoveCharFromString(input.Remove(indexOfChar, 1), charItem);
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

It always bugged me that there's no way to "remove a char from a string", only "string from a string".

I took a modified version of Alexei Bondarev's answer and behcmarked it against the standard `string.Replace(string, "")`

```
|               Method |     Mean |     Error |   StdDev |  Gen 0 | Allocated |
|--------------------- |---------:|----------:|---------:|-------:|----------:|
|        StringReplace | 57.28 ns | 14.701 ns | 0.806 ns | 0.0063 |      40 B |
| RemoveCharFromString | 51.62 ns |  4.604 ns | 0.252 ns | 0.0216 |     136 B |
```

As you can see the results are nearly identical, but the 'RemoveCharFromString' allocates 3X memory.

The moral is - stick to `String.Replace(string, "")`

For reference, this is the method I used:

```
public static string RemoveCharFromString(string input, char charItem)
{
    int indexOfChar = input.IndexOf(charItem);
    while (indexOfChar >= 0)
    {
        input = input.Remove(indexOfChar, 1);
        indexOfChar = input.IndexOf(charItem, indexOfChar);
    }
    return input;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It always bothered me that I can't use the `String.Remove` method to get rid of instances of a string or character in a string so I usually add theses extension methods to my code base:

```cs
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Remove(this string str, string toBeRemoved)
    {
        return str.Replace(toBeRemoved, "");
    }

    public static string RemoveChar(this string str, char toBeRemoved)
    {
        return str.Replace(toBeRemoved.ToString(), "");

    }
}
```

The one taking `char` can't use overload semantics unfortunately since it will resolve to `string.Remove(int startIndex)` since it is ["closer"](https://ericlippert.com/2013/12/23/closer-is-better/)

This is of course purely esthetics, but I like it...

Answer (score 1):

If you are in a loop, let's say that you loop through a list of punctuation characters that you want to remove, you can do something like this:

```
      private const string PunctuationChars = ".,!?$";
          foreach (var word in words)
                {
                    var word_modified = word;

                    var modified = false;

                    foreach (var punctuationChar in PunctuationChars)
                    {
                        if (word.IndexOf(punctuationChar) > 0)
                        {
                            modified = true;
                            word_modified = word_modified.Replace("" + punctuationChar, "");


                        }
                    }
               //////////MORE CODE
               }
```

The trick being the following:

```
word_modified.Replace("" + punctuationChar, "");
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a latin version of the code of Razvan Dumitru because us use a million indicator even. Offcourse I use a double replace :D

```
public static string CleanNumb(string numb) 
{
    foreach (char c in ".,'´")
       numb = numb.Replace(c, ' ');

    return numb.Replace(" ", "");
}
```