# VB to C# equivalent Split Function

Tags: c#, vb.net

i have that VB code...

```
Dim htcsplit() As String = Split(value.Text.Replace(" ", ""), ",")
```

try to adapt this for c#.

Unluckily i cant write

```
string[] htcsplit = String.Split(value.Text.Replace(' ', null),',');
```

Because the literal cant be empty.

Is there a workaround ?

Comment: It's the replace function - take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6373315/how-to-replace-a-char-in-string-with-an-empty-character-in-c-net

Comment: You might find Convert .NET a useful tool. It's a desktop tool with integrated RegEx-Tester and VB.Net<=>C# translation: https://fishcodelib.com/Convert.htm among other functions.

Comment: Is there a reason you changed from the *string* `" "` to the *char* `' '`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
string[] htcsplit = value.Text.Replace(" ", "").Split(',');
```

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent in C# should be:

```
string[] htcsplit = value.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

or (if you have a `Split` method)

```
string[] htcsplit = Split(value.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty), ',');
```

Example `Split` method:

```
string[] Split(string input, char separator)
{
    return input.Split(separator);
}
```

There are some converters out there which could help you:

- https://converter.telerik.com/
- https://www.carlosag.net/tools/codetranslator/

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "" you can use **string.Empty** 
This replaces the value as **string** instead of a character, but should bring the same result. The string with the replaced characters can be split by a char or string.

Try:

```
string[] htcsplit = value.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(',');
```

or

```
string[] htcsplit = value.Text.Replace(" ", string.Empty).Split(",");
```

Comment: There is no difference between "" and `string.Empty`. As I see it, using `string.Empty` is recommended for readability and avoiding unnecessary compiler generated constants, but in the latter case I assume that the compiler nowadays is smart enough to optimize even multiple "" literals.

Comment: Yep,  "" equals string.Empty. I wanted to point out, that the replace function is now based on the string datatype instead of char, as the OP had originally tried to write. And "" looks always a little bit tinkered to me. ;o)