# remove the '\' character from a string

Tags: c#, string

I want to remove the `'\'` character from my strings.

I've tried several ways but I am still not having any luck

Here is a small piece of my code.  It is in fact an HTML obtained from another site.

I'm going to use it at my own site but \ makes problems!

```
 src=\"http://bartarinha.com/file/logo/ideal.jpg\" style=\"border: 0px none\">
```

This code gives me error:

```
news_body_html = news_body_html.Replace("\", " ");
```

What is the correct way to remove the character?

Comment: Are you sure there are \ characters or is it just the Visual Studio debugger that shows you the string in C# syntax?

Comment: how can I understand it? when I copy paste the text in notepad, there are some instances of this string

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: Copy paste the text *from where*?

Comment: I go over my string in VS, and copy its text right into notepad, and I have these \ characters, what is the correct way? I want to use this variable for displaying in my ASP.NET DIV –

Comment: I think that VS added thoes to the string. They are not actually there. There should be a pulldown at the start of the string when you hover over it that allows you to select a 'visualizer'. Then select the "text visualizer".

Comment: oh yes I think it is the trick!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

try news_body_html.Replace("\\", " ");

or news_body_html.Replace(@"\", " ");

Comment: I keep forgetting about using the @ symbol for literal strings. I prefer that method.

Answer (score 7):

Have a go with

```
news_body_html = news_body_html.Replace("\\", " ");
```

EDIT:

Actually try this:

```
news_body_html = news_body_html.Replace('\\', ' ');
```

Note that I'm using single quotes here around the slashes. I forgot that Replace expects a char as the parameter.

Comment: I have tested it with no luck! I have still this \ character

Answer (score 4):

You have to escape the escape character:

```
news_body_html = news_body_html.Replace("\\", " ");
```

Comment: @Ali_dotNet: It really should. I strongly suspect your diagnostics are at fault here - for example, are you looking at the string in a debugger?

Comment: yes I go over my string in VS, and copy its text right into notepad, and I have these \ characters, what is the correct way? I want to use this variable for displaying in my ASP.NET DIV

Answer (score 3):

```
news_body_html = news_body_html.Replace("\\", " ");
```

That will remove the \ from your code.
the \ is a control used most commonly for \n to make a new line, so it was seeing it as a command with nothing to do, therefore doing nothing with it.

Answer (score 2):

The follwoing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/894905/how-to-replace-occurrences-of-with-an-empty-string) asks about replacing "-" from a string but the same method should work for your problem.

Just remember that to use \ in a c# string you need to use "\" as it is a single \is an escape character