# Best practice for denoting empty string - C#

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [In C#, should I use string.Empty or String.Empty or “” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or)
>   [What is the difference between String.Empty and “”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)

Should I use:

```
 - string.Empty
 - String.Empty
 - ""
```

when I want to return an empty string from a method (or anywhere else for that matter)

Comment: Dupliacte http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.Empty & string.Empty are exactly the same.