# .NET equivalent to Perl regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex, perl

I need to convert a Perl script to VB.NET. I have managed almost the entire conversion, but some Perl (seemingly simple) regular expressions are causing an headache. What is the .NET equivalent of the following Perl regular expressions?

1)

```
    $letter =~ s/Users //,;
    $letter =~ s/Mailboxes //,;
    if($letter =~ m/$first_char/i){
```

2)

```
    unless($storegroup =~ /Recovery/ || $storegroup =~ /Users U V W X Y Z/ || $storegroup =~ /Users S T/
        || $storegroup =~ /Users Q R/){
```

The regular expressions look simple to me. I tried to wade through perl.org, but understanding a language's regular expressions takes some time.

Comment: What do these regex do? Not everyone learned Perl but they may know the .net Regex.

Comment: Well, that's what I am trying to find out. If some Perl guy can explain in simple English, what these regex do, I would be able to convert them to .NET!!!

Comment: I think that's the problem for the OP as well :)

Comment: Your first two expressions carry an additional comma – I’m no Perl person but I don’t think they belong there … and *if* they do then these expressions might do something else than just replace the strings in the expressions.

Comment: Possible duplicate: *[Translate Perl regular expressions to .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417644/translate-perl-regular-expressions-to-net)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Perl, you can think of the slashes as something like double-quotes with the added meaning of "between these slashes is a regex-string". The first block of code is a Perl find/replace regular expression:

```
$stringvar =~ s/findregex/replaceregex/;
```

It takes `findregex` and replaces it with `replaceregex`, in-place. The given example is a very simple search, and the .NET *Regex* class would be overkill.  `String.Replace()` method will do the job:

```
letter = letter.Replace("Users ", "")
letter = letter.Replace("Mailboxes ", "")
```

The second part is Perl for find only. It returns `true` if the findregex string is found and leaves the actual string itself untouched.

```
$stringvar =~ /findregex/;
```

`String.Contains()` can handle this in .NET:

```
if (!(storegroup.Contains("Recovery") _
   or storegroup.Contains("Users U V W X Y Z") _
   or storegroup.Contains("you get the idea"))) Then
    ...
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, so you mean, the first part is a substitution pattern (s/text //) while the second part is a normal regex search??

Comment: Thanks Daniel, can you please also comment on this:
if($letter =~ m/$first_char/i)

Comment: Any particular reason for using the bloated `String.Empty` in place of just `""`?

Comment: But you know, I think Regex itself is a little bloated for this job in VB.net.  Built-in string operations should cover these operations just fine.

Comment: "" and string.Empty were slightly different beasts, at least back in .NET 1.0 and 1.1 (see http://blogs.msdn.com/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx) but I've no idea if this has changed since.  I got into the habit of using string.Empty back then and just haven't kicked it yet!

Comment: @Daniel Renshaw: They actually haven’t – so yes, **technically** there is a slight difference but I’ll challenge anyone who claims that this is a valid reason to use the bogus construct `String.Empty`. If you do, at least be consistent and use `Int32.Zero` instead of `0`. Oh wait, that doesn’t exist ….

Comment: @daniel `m` here does not mean «multiply lines». Here `m/.../` means «whatever is enclosed with `/` is a regex pattern». And `m/$first_char/i` searches for *pattern* represented by variable `$first_char`, not for *string*. There will be no difference if `$first_char` does not contain special symbols, but without other code you cannot be sure.

Comment: @Konrad: no such claim from me - just offering a bit of information that some may find interesting.  Even so, MS presumably felt there was enough of a difference to offer `string.Empty` so maybe "bogus" is putting it a little strongly.  However, more reasons to use `""` instead here: http://dotnetperls.com/string-empty and a SO discussion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and

Comment: @ZyX, thanks for the correction, I'm deleting my comment on this to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $letter =~ s/Users //,;
    $letter =~ s/Mailboxes //,;
    if($letter =~ m/$first_char/i){
```

-->

```
    letter = letter.Replace("Users ", "");
    letter = letter.Replace("Mailboxes ", "");
    // The next one depends on what $first_char is
```

and

```
    unless($storegroup =~ /Recovery/ || $storegroup =~ /Users U V W X Y Z/ || $storegroup =~ /Users S T/
    || $storegroup =~ /Users Q R/){
```

-->

```
    if (!(storegroup.Contains("Recovery") || storegroup.Contains("Users U V W X Y Z") ...and so on...))
```

The only reason to use regular expressions here is because Perl is super good at regular expressions :)

Comment: But that is not VB.NET code (the "to" code). E.g., the comment character in VB.NET is `'`.