# Translate Perl regular expressions to .NET

Tags: c#, .net, regex, perl

I have some useful [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) in Perl. Is there a simple way to translate them to .NET's dialect of regular expressions?

If not, is there a concise reference of differences?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

There is a big comparison table in http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html.

---

Most of the basic elements are the same, the differences are:

**Minor differences:**

- Unicode escape sequences. In .NET it is `\u200A`, in Perl it is `\x{200A}`.
- `\v` in .NET is just the vertical tab (U+000B), in Perl it stands for the "vertical whitespace" class. Of course there is `\V` in Perl because of this.
- The conditional expression for named reference in .NET is `(?(name)yes|no)`, but `(?(<name>)yes|no)` in Perl.

**Some elements are Perl-only:**

- Possessive quantifiers (`x?+`, `x*+`, `x++` etc). Use non-backtracking subexpression (`(?>…)`) instead.
- Named unicode escape sequence `\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER X}`, `\N{U+200A}`.
- Case folding and escaping

  - `\l` (lower case next char), `\u` (upper case next char).
  - `\L` (lower case), `\U` (upper case), `\Q` (quote meta characters) until `\E`.
- Shorthand notation for Unicode property `\pL` and `\PL`.  You have to include the braces in .NET e.g. `\p{L}`.
- Odd things like `\X`, `\C`.
- Special character classes like `\v`, `\V`, `\h`, `\H`, `\N`, `\R`
- Backreference to a specific or previous group `\g1`, `\g{-1}`. You can only use absolute group index in .NET.
- Named backreference `\g{name}`. Use `\k<name>` instead.
- POSIX character class `[[:alpha:]]`.
- Branch-reset pattern `(?|…)`
- `\K`. Use look-behind (`(?<=…)`) instead.
- Code evaluation assertion `(?{…})`, post-poned subexpression `(??{…})`.
- Subexpression reference (recursive pattern) `(?0)`, `(?R)`, `(?1)`, `(?-1)`, `(?+1)`, `(?&name)`.
- Some conditional expression's predicate are Perl-specific:

  - code `(?{…})`
  - recursive `(R)`, `(R1)`, `(R&name)`
  - define `(DEFINE)`.
- Special Backtracking Control Verbs `(*VERB:ARG)`
- Python syntax

  - `(?P<name>…)`. Use `(?<name>…)` instead.
  - `(?P=name)`. Use `\k<name>` instead.
  - `(?P>name)`. No equivalent in .NET.

**Some elements are .NET only:**

- Variable length look-behind. In Perl, for positive look-behind, use `\K` instead.
- Arbitrary regular expression in conditional expression `(?(pattern)yes|no)`.
- Character class subtraction (undocumented?) `[a-z-[d-w]]`
- Balancing Group `(?<-name>…)`. This could be simulated with code evaluation assertion `(?{…})` followed by a `(?&name)`.

References:

- [*.NET Framework 4: Regular Expression Language Elements*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx)
- [*perlre*](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html)

Comment: Awesome, thanks... BTW, I was quite pleasantly surprised at how compatible the 2 dialects are... even look-around, etc.  I also had not known that the Regex.Replace method in .NET supported replacing matched parenthesized subexpressions ($1, $2, etc.) like so: str = Regex.Replace(str, @"([a-z]+):(\d+)", m => m.Result("$1 -- $2")) which corresponds to the Perl: s/([a-z]+):(\d+)/$1 -- $2/g

Comment: "Some elements are Perl-only" does not mention character translation (like tr/tgca/acgt/), so it is supported, isn'T it?

Comment: @mbx: I don't consider character translation as part of regex.

Comment: Great answer. I'd like to add this: When you mix named and unnamed capture groups in a single regex, the _order_ in which they are referenced is different. In Perl, `perl -E "@captures =  'word1 word2 word3' =~ /(?<name1>\w+)\s+(\w+)\s+(\w+)/; foreach my $c (@captures){say $c}"` still comes out as `word1 word2 word3`, whereas in .NET regex it would come out as `word2 word3 word1` because unnamed groups are -unexpectedly- prioritized when the capture groups are ordered by the regex engine. This might have implications when complex regexes are translated from one language into the other.

Answer (score 4):

They were [designed to be compatible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312(VS.71).aspx) with Perl 5 regexes. As such, Perl 5 regexes *should* just work in .NET.

You can translate some `RegexOptions` as follows:

```
[Flags]
public enum RegexOptions
{
  Compiled = 8,
  CultureInvariant = 0x200,
  ECMAScript = 0x100,
  ExplicitCapture = 4,
  IgnoreCase = 1,                 // i in Perl
  IgnorePatternWhitespace = 0x20, // x in Perl
  Multiline = 2,                  // m in Perl
  None = 0,
  RightToLeft = 0x40,
  Singleline = 0x10               // s in Perl
}
```

Another tip is to use verbatim strings so that you don't need to escape all those escape characters in C#:

```
string badOnTheEyesRx    = "\\d{4}/\\d{2}/\\d{2}";
string easierOnTheEyesRx = @"\d{4}/\d{2}/\d{2}";
```

Comment: @Eric: Neither is a superset of the other.

Comment: No, .NET came after Perl 5, and copied it's winning regex syntax.

Comment: @KennyTM => what does .NET have that Perl does not?  Perl has embedded code execution `(?{ code })` and `(??{ code })`, recursion into capture groups...

Comment: @Eric: [Balancing groups](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/balancing-groups).

Comment: @KennyTM => i haven't looked into them much, but it looks like that could be done with Perl's embedded code constructs.  At any rate, calling .NET's regexes a superset of Perl's is just wrong.

Comment: Oh yeah, code interpolation won't work in .NET, unless you do some ugly string concatenation or use `string.Format` to create your regexes. And the fact that they're not literals in .NET is also not ideal.

Comment: @Eric: (1) That's cheating ;) (2) I did not call .NET is a superset of Perl. I call they belong the different sets (Insert Venn diagram).

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the complexity of the regular expression - many ones will work the same out of the box.

Take a look at [this](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) .NET regex cheat sheet to see if an operator does what you expect it to do.

I don't know of any tool that automatically translates between RegEx dialects.

Comment: RegexBuddy can take a regex in a large variety of flavors and convert it to another - as long as the required functionality is supported by the target regex flavor.