# Support of \K in regex

Tags: regex

The `\K` escape sequence resets the beginning of the match to the current position in
the token list (this only affects what is reported as the full match).

What environments/languages/versions support `\K` (keep) in its regular expression engines and what libraries are needed (if any) to use this feature within patterns?

Comment: To aid searches, `\K` is also known as a regular expression [metacharacter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metacharacter).

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The `\K` escape sequence is supported by several engines, languages or tools, such as:

- boost (since ???)
- grep -P --------------------⇢ *Uses PCRE*
- Oniguruma ([since 5.13.3](https://github.com/k-takata/Onigmo/blob/master/README))
- PCRE ([since 7.2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perl_Compatible_Regular_Expressions))
- Perl ([since 5.10.0](http://search.cpan.org/%7Ergarcia/perl/pod/perl5100delta.pod))
- PHP ([since 5.2.4](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php))
- Ruby (since 2.0.0 due to its use of the Onigmo engine (a fork of Oniguruma))
- Notepad++ ([since 6.0](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/news/notepad-6.0-release.html))

...and (so far) not supported by:

- [.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417644/translate-perl-regex-to-net)
- awk
- bash
- [ICU](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp)
- [Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)
- Javascript
- Objective-C
- POSIX
- Python
- Qt/QRegExp
- sed
- Tcl
- vim --------------------⇢ *It doesn't have `\K`, but its `\zs` is equivalent*
- XML
- XPath

Comment: AutoIt does too. Not sure how long it has support it for though.

Comment: This answer has been added to the [Stack Overflow Regular Expression FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075/2736496), under "Lookarounds".

Comment: \k named backreferences are supported in .NET: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/backreference-constructs-in-regular-expressions#named-backreferences

Comment: @juFo I think the question is about uppercase `\K` which is different from lowercase `\k` in regex.