# Regular expression to match, in a sentence, words within brackets

Tags: regex

I need an regular expression to match, in a sentence, words within brackets. For example:

```
"this is [stack]overflow. I [[love]this[website]]."
```

what i want to match from the sentence above are the words stack, love and website.

I've tried the folowing regexp `\[(.*[^\]\[])\]` but it doesn't work.

Comment: Welcome to [SO]; please review the [faq].

Comment: Please specify the regex flavor (as required in the tag description).

Comment: I find the votes a little harsh on this question. The question could have been better asked but that's neither so easy nor so localized.

Comment: Was this downvoted so much just because it didn't include a question mark?  The OP clearly described the problem and showed what he tried... Too localized?  You could say that about almost all regex questions.

Answer (score 4):

The following should work:

```
\[([^\[\]]*)\]
```

Example: http://www.rubular.com/r/uJ0sOtdcgF

Explanation:

```
\[           # match a literal '['
(            # start a capturing group
  [^\[\]]*     # match any number of characters that are not '[' or ']'
)            # end of capturing group
\]           # match a literal ']'
```

Comment: thank you for the answer F.J. It works. I'm sorry for not following posting policy on this website but i'm a newbie with a need of urgent helping.

Comment: @Jdoe - Your question was very close to good.  Next time make sure your title attempts to describe your problem, "I need a regular expression" is too vague (I edited your question to fix this).  Also, even though it was clear what you wanted, include a question.  Something like "How can I fix this?" to the end would be sufficient.

Comment: @Jdoe - And with regex questions, include the language or tool you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try doing this in a [shell](/questions/tagged/shell) :

```
$ echo 'this is [stack]overflow. I [[love]this[website]]' |
    grep -oP '\[+\K[^\]]+'
stack
love
website
```

This works with PCRE & perl engines.

**EXPLANATIONS**

```
\[           # match a literal '['
+            # one (preceding character) or more
\K           # "reset" the regex to null
[^]          # excluding class, here a literal \]
\]           # match a literal ']'
```

[explanations about `\K` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex/13543042#13543042)

Comment: This will match `this[website` in `[this[website]]`. Also, as your link says, it will not work in most flavors, which is a shame for such a simple requirement.