# Regular Expression Pattern \K Alternatives in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have a regex expression that I tested on http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ and it worked, but when I used it in my C# application it failed.

My regex expression: `(?<!\d)\d{6}\K\d+(?=\d{4}(?!\d))`
Text: 4000751111115425
Result: 111111

What is wrong with my regex expression?

Comment: .NET's regular expression engine doesn't support `\K`. I believe the closest you can get is `(?<!\d)\d{6}(\d+)(?=\d{4}(?!\d))` and then look at `match.Groups[1].Value` rather than `match.Value`. (N.B. this would be an answer if a ♦ hadn't one-shot closed this question.)

Comment: However I think you're overcomplicating things. `(?<=\d{6})\d+(?=\d{4})` should work as well because the `+` is greedy.

Comment: \K is not supported by the .NET regex implementation: http://stackoverflow.com/q/13542950/736079 and this can indeed be solved by a look behind or by using a Capturing group. or

Comment: @Rawling It appears you can post your answer as an answer now.

Answer (score 8):

This issue you are having is that .NET regular expressions do not support `\K`, "discard what has been matched so far".

I believe your regex translates as "match any string of more than ten `\d` digits, to as many digits as possible, and discard the first 6 and the last 4".

I believe that the .NET-compliant regex

```
(?<=\d{6})\d+(?=\d{4})
```

achieves the same thing. Note that the negative lookahead/behind for no-more-`\d`s is not necessary as the `\d+` is greedy - the engine already will try to match as many digits as possible.

Comment: and what if I have this regex (will delete empty spaces from a tag) `\s\S*(?:<p class="text_obisnuit">|\G)(?:(?!</p>).)*?\s\K\s+|(?<=<p class="text_obisnuit">)\s+|\s+(?=</p>)` ? What will be the \K alternative ?

Comment: @JustMe I feel like you'd just put the bit before the `\K` into positive lookbehind, like the second alternate already uses (`(?<= ... )`)

Answer (score 0):

In general, `\K` operator (that discards all text matched so far from the match memory buffer) can be emulated with two techniques:

- [Lookarounds](https://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Capturing groups](https://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html) (with and without lookarounds).

For example,

- PCRE `a+b+c+=\K\d+` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bWV6fG/2)) = .NET `(?<=a+b+c+=)\d+` or `a+b+c+=(\d+)` (and grab Group 1 value)
- PCRE `^[^][]+\K.*` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/bWV6fG/1)) = .NET `(?<=^[^][]+)(?:\[.*)?$` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3c%3d%5e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5c%5b.*%29%3f%24&i=03%2f16-21%3a36%3a16.512226++%5b**%5d+Some+random+Text)) or (better here) `^[^][]+(.*)` ([demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5e%5d%5b%5d%2b%28.*%29&i=03%2f16-21%3a36%3a16.512226++%5b**%5d+Some+random+Text)).

The problem with the second example is that `[^][]+` can match the same text as `.*` (these patterns overlap) and since there is no clear boundary between the two patterns, just using a lookbehind is not actually working and needs additional tricks to make it work.

**Capturing group** approach is universal here and should work in all situations.

Since `\K` makes the regex engine "forget" the part of a match consumed so far, the best approach here is to use a *capturing group* to grab the part of a match you need to obtain after the left-hand context:

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var text = "Text  4000751111115425";
        var result = Regex.Match(text, @"(?<!\d)\d{6}(\d+)(?=\d{4}(?!\d))")?.Groups[1].Value;
        Console.WriteLine($"Result: '{result}'");
    }
}
```

See the [online C# demo](https://ideone.com/WEKIS0) and the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C!%5Cd%29%5Cd%7B6%7D%28%5Cd%2B%29%28%3F%3D%5Cd%7B4%7D%28%3F!%5Cd%29%29&i=Text%3A%204000751111115425%0D%0AResult%3A%20111111) (see *Table* tab for the proper result table). **Details**:

- `(?<!\d)` - a left-hand digit boundary
- `\d{6}` - six digits
- `(\d+)` - **Capturing group 1**: one or more digits
- `(?=\d{4}(?!\d))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with four digits not immediately followed with another digit.