# Regular expression to match a string into a text

Tags: regex

I've a TXT file and I use a Reg Expr to get the text after a string
"Diagnosis Statement:"

the Full text is :

```
Diagnosis Statement:
6/28/2011
RZZZCG77T77G355S
Report text is here ....... end of report
```

I would get only the 16 digits "RZZZCG77T77G355S" into the text
(16 digits mix of numbers and capital letters)

I can get the text after the string "Diagnosis Statement:" with :

```
(?ms)^Diagnosis Statement\s*:(?<value>.*)
```

and I get the code with :

```
^[A-Z0-9]{16}?$
```

But cannot get the correct way to merge both and get only the 16 digits string from
text after "Diagnosis Statement:"

Can you give some help ?

Comment: Try `(?m)^Diagnosis Statement\s*:\s*\d{1,2}/\d{1,2}/\d{4}\s*(?<value>[A-Z0-9]{16})`, see [the regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qrvy0m/2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your example, `^([A-Z0-9]{16})$` is enough. Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/CnYF8r/1).

Do you have another place in the document where you find text with a format of 16 char, with only captials and digits ? If no, this regex is enough.

With the following regex, you can find the first thing you find with the good format, following "Diagnosis Statement:" and one line of random text.

```
Diagnosis Statement:\s*.*\s*\K^([A-Z0-9]{16})$
```

Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/CnYF8r/4)

Comment: Thank you very much , this get the match perfectly !

Comment: I removed the useless `\K` @Thefourthbird ;)

Comment: Hello, I see The regex  works fine in regex101.com, as are PHP expressions.
When tried in C#, it throws an error saying \K is an unrecognized escape sequence.
Do you know how to format it for C#? Thanks a lot

Comment: Following [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14200596/regular-expression-pattern-k-alternatives-in-c-sharp) question, the `\K` symbol is not supported. I'll search for a workaround and come back to you if I find a good one

Comment: You could just use the first Regex I put in the answer for the moment

Comment: Here is a workaround : `(Diagnosis Statement:\s*.*\s*)^([A-Z0-9]{16})$`. It will match the whole statement, with 2 groups. The first one is useless. Just save the second one and you're good. Test it [here](https://regex101.com/r/CnYF8r/5)

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot, I see is working fine on : https://regex101.com/ but for some reason is not on: http://regexstorm.net/tester that was a suggested site to test C# , I'm checking to see why .