# how to extract substring and numbers only using grep/sed

Tags: regex, linux, bash, sed

I have a text file containing both text and numbers, I want to use grep to extract only the numbers I need for example, given a file as follow:

```
miss rate 0.21  
ipc 222  
stalls n shdmem 112
```

So say I only want to extract the data for `miss rate` which is `0.21`. How do I do it with grep or sed? Plus, I need more than one number, not only the one after `miss rate`. That is, I may want to get both `0.21` and `112`. A sample output might look like this:

```
0.21 222 112
```

Cause I need the data for later plot.

Comment: I recommend using sed instead of grep if that works for you

Comment: sed is also acceptable if it works more elegantly in this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `awk` instead:

```
awk '/^miss rate/ { print $3 }' yourfile
```

To do it with just grep, you need non-standard extensions like here with GNU grep using PCRE (-P) with positive lookbehind (?<=..) and match only (-o):

```
grep -Po '(?<=miss rate ).*' yourfile
```

Answer (score 8):

If you *really* want to use only grep for this, then you can try:

```
grep "miss rate" file | grep -oe '\([0-9.]*\)'
```

It will first find the line that matches, and then only output the digits.

Sed might be a bit more readable, though:

```
sed -n 's#miss rate ##p' file
```

Answer (score 4):

Using the special *look around* regex trick [\K](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex) with [pcre](/questions/tagged/pcre) engine with [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
grep -oP 'miss rate \K.*' file.txt
```

or with [perl](/questions/tagged/perl) :

```
perl -lne 'print $& if /miss rate \K.*/' file.txt
```

Comment: Added Perl portable solution =)

Comment: the \K trick is really helpful. Yes I prefer grep to do this since I am not an expert in awk and also a prob with awk is the field separator since the text in a single field can have multiple and varying #spaces as in 'miss rate XX' and 'stalls total number XXX'

Answer (score 4):

The `grep`-and-`cut` solution would look like:

to get the 3rd field for every successful grep use:

```
grep "^miss rate " yourfile | cut -d ' ' -f 3
```

or to get the 3rd field and the rest use:

```
grep "^miss rate " yourfile | cut -d ' ' -f 3-
```

Or if you use bash and "miss rate" only occurs once in your file you can also just do:

```
a=( $(grep -m 1 "miss rate" yourfile) )
echo ${a[2]}
```

where `${a[2]}` is your result.

If "miss rate" occurs more then once you can loop over the grep output reading only what you need. (in bash)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
grep -P "miss rate \d+(\.\d+)?" file.txt
```

or:

```
grep -E "miss rate [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?"
```

Both of those commands will print out `miss rate 0.21`. If you want to extract the number only, why not use Perl, Sed or Awk?

If you really want to avoid those, maybe this will work?

```
grep -E "miss rate [0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?" g | xargs basename | tail -n 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe

`sed 's|[^0-9]*\([0-9\.]*\)|\1 |g' fiilename`

will do the trick. However every entry will be on it's own line if that is ok. I am sure there is a way for sed to produce a comma or space delimited list but I am not a super master of all things sed.

Comment: I adapted this a bit to pull a 5 digit ticket number (always the first 5 numbers on the line) via \([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]\) as the capture group.