# Print a value from a HTML variable on linux Shell

Tags: html, shell, variables

I'm trying to print the value of a variable on an HTML file
The file could be called something.html and I need to print the number inside of the nbLineValue variable, which, in this case, is 77

```
<span class="nbLineLabel"></span><span class="nbLineValue">77</span>
```

Any ideas?

EDIT: I managed to solve the problem with the following code

```
grep -oP '<span class="nbLineLabel"></span><span class="nbLineValue">\K[[:digit:]]*' something.html
```

Comment: Provide a [mcve] by [editing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/47964222/edit) your post. Your description isn't clear and unambiguous enough for it to be clear what you're asking for.

Comment: Do you want the inner HTML from any element with the `nbLineValue` class? Or only from `span` elements, or only from elements with "simple text" in their body?

Comment: I'm a total noob on HTML what I need is the value of the number where the 77 is. He will change on each file

Comment: Here's an idea: use `awk` or `grep` with appropriate regular expression ...  also take a look at [how-to-extract-substring-and-numbers-only-using-grep-sed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15371450/how-to-extract-substring-and-numbers-only-using-grep-sed)...

Comment: HTML doesn't have native variables. Do you mean line number of `nbLineValue`, or are you trying to use some sort of a templating system, to generate the HTML file? Please clarify in your question.

Comment: I want the number of the nbLineValue

Answer (score 1):

Using a regex is a bad choice for parsing data in XML/HTML - see [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

You can use `htmlutils`, however - on [Debian](https://packages.debian.org/source/stretch/html-xml-utils), [Ubuntu](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/html-xml-utils), and [Arch](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/html-xml-utils/), the package is `html-xml-utils`. This comes with an application [`hxselect`](https://www.w3.org/Tools/HTML-XML-utils/man1/hxselect.html), which can perform HTML parsing on the command line using CSS selectors. From the docs page:

> `hxselect [ -i ] [ -c ] [ -l language ] [ -s separator ] selectors`
>
> `hxselect` reads a well-formed XML document and outputs all elements and attributes that match one of the CSS selectors that are given as an argument.

In your case, you can use a command like:

```
cat something.html | hxselect -i -c -s '\n' .nbLineValue
```

The options used here read as follows:

- `-i`: Match case-insensitively. This is good for HTML where element tags can be any case.
- `-c`: Display only the content (body) of each element, not the tags surrounding it. This ensures you just get `77`, not all the surrounding.
- `-s '\n'`: Output a single newline after each matching element, for ease of parsing.
- `.nbLineValue`: Select all elements with class `nbLineValue`

Comment: It gives me the following output "Input is not well-formed. (Maybe try normalize?)"

Comment: With a file containing just the file contents you showed in your answer, and using the command line above, I get `77`. What's different between your setup and what you've put in your question?

Comment: There is more code inside of that HTML not only that single line that I post. With only that code it works, with the whole file not :/

Comment: @SérgioBeltrão Okay, post more of the file in your question or upload it to a file sharing site and send a link. You'll have invalid HTML in it somewhere. The `hxselect` application should point out the line number of syntax errors.

Comment: 'grep -oP '<span class="nbLineLabel"></span><span class="nbLineValue">\K[[:digit:]]*' something.html' Solved the problem. Thanks for your time!