# Need a regular expression to return text from last "/" to last "-"

Tags: regex

I just cant seem to be able to figure out how to match the following

in the string `/hello/there-my-friend`

I need to capture everything after the last `/` and before the last `-`

So it should capture `there-my`.

Comment: A technique called **lookahead** might be needed.  See the reference: http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Which language are you writing this in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will do it:

```
(?!.*?/).*(?=-)
```

Depending on your language, you might need to escape the `/`

Breakdown:

```
1. (?!.*?/) - Negative look ahead. It will start collecting characters after the last `/`
2. .*       - Looks for all characters
3. (?=-)    - Positive look ahead. It means step 2 should only go up to the last `-`
```

Edited after comment: No longer includes the `/` and the last `-` in the results.

Comment: I am using regexpal to test this. Close but this seems to include the last / and -. I need the text between them.

Comment: @everreadyeddy I updated to remove the last `/` and the last `-`

Answer (score 2):

Here's the Regular Expression you're looking for:

```
#(?<=/)[^/]+(?=-[^-/]*$)#
```

I'll break it down in a minute, but there are probably better ways to do this.

I might do something like this:

```
$str = "/hello/there-my-friend";
$pieces = explode('/', $str);
$afterLastSlash = $pieces[count($pieces)-1];
$dashes = explode('-', $afterLastSlash);
unset($dashes[count($dashes)-1]);
$result = implode('-', $dashes);
```

The performance here is guaranteed linear (limiting factor being the length of $str plus the length of $afterLastSlash.  The regular expression is going to be much slower (as much as polynomial time, I think - it can get a little dicey with lookarounds.)

The code above could easily be pared down, but the naming makes it more clear.  Here it is as a one liner:

```
$result = implode('-', array_slice(explode('-', array_slice(explode('/', $str), -1)), 0, -1));
```

But gross, don't do that.  Find a middle ground.

As promised, a breakdown of the regular expression:

```
#
    (?<=        Look behind an ensure there's a...
        /       Literal forward slash.
    )           Okay, done looking behind.
    [^/]        Match any character that's not a forward slash
    +           ...One ore more times.
    (?=         Now look ahead, and ensure there's...
        -       a hyphen.
        [^-/]   followed by any non-hyphen, non-forward slash character
        *       zero or more times
        $       until the end of the string.
     )          Okay, done looking ahead.
#
```

Comment: Hm.  I conflated this with another question I was considering answering, and wrote the answer with PHP regex in mind.  If that's not your flavor, let me know and I'll translate.

Comment: I am using regexpal to test the expression and this does not look to working

Comment: Regexpal is javascript.  Are you using javascript?  Because javascript does not tolerate lookarounds.  If you're not using javascript: Try http://gskinner.com/RegExr/.  And remember to leave off the delimiters.  If you are using javascript, hold on a minute.

Comment: If you are using javascript:  `"/hello/there-my-friend".match(/\/([^\/]+)-[^-\/]*$/)[1]` produces `"there-my"`.

Comment: @everreadyeddy : here's a direct link to the RegExr with this regex. http://regexr.com?34796

Comment: Looks to be working. Had to change it slightly to get it working on regexpal to [^/]+(?=-[^-/]*$)

Answer (score 1):

```
^".*/([^/-]*)-[^/-]*$
```

Syntax may vary depending on which flavor of RE you are using.

Answer (score 1):

Try this short regex :

```
/\K\w+-\w+
```

Your regex engine need [`\K` support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex)

or

```
(?<=/)\w+-\w+
```

(more portable)

### Explanations

- `\K` is close to `(?<=/)` : a [*look-around* regex advanced technique](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444)
- `\w` is the same as `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`, feel free to adapt it

Answer (score 0):

This is not an exact answer to your question (its not a regex), but if you are using C# you might use this:

```
string str = "/hello/there-my-friend";
int lastSlashIndex = str.LastIndexOf('/');
int lastDashIndex = str.LastIndexOf('-');

return str.Substring(lastSlashIndex, lastDashIndex - lastSlashIndex);
```