# Parse value between two strings in bash

Tags: linux, bash, curl, sed, grep

I am pretty newe to linux and even though I need something simple I dont know where to start. In a bash script I need to parse the value from a HTML page between the string "VOL. " and "," and pass it to a variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
newvar=$(grep -oP 'VOL\.\K.*?(?=,)' file.txt)
echo "$newvar"
```

or from a string :

```
newvar=$(grep -oP 'VOL\.\K.*?(?=,)' <<< "$string")
echo "$newvar"
```

if you need something more portable :

```
newvar=$(perl -lne '/VOL\.\K.*?(?=,)/ && print $&' <<< "$string")
echo "$newvar"
```

### Explanations of the Regex

- `VOL\.` = literal `VOL.` : the `.` = any character in `regex` without backslash
- `\K`    = restart the match to zero, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/465183
- `.*?`   = any character, 0 to N occurrences but non-greedy with `?` char
- `(?=,)` = it's a *positive look-ahead assertion* to look up the `,` char

Comment: Note that `-P` is a gnu flag and not available on most non-Linux systems, e.g. Macs and other BSDs.

Comment: Yes, but OP have `linux` tag ;)

Comment: Anyway, added a more portable `perl` solution.

Comment: Thanks sputnick, that works. Just for the sake of understanding it is 'VOL\.\K.*?(?=,)' regex? Because I tried to make this expressions works with no success: (?<=VOL. )(.*)(?=,)

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using bash's built-in regex matching:

```
if [[ "$var" =~ "VOL. "([^,]*)"," ]]; then
    match="${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
fi
```