# How negative lookbehind works in below example?

Tags: regex, perl

Why on applying regular expression(rx) on data(d) gives output(o) ?
Regular expression (rx):

```
s/(?<!\#include)[\s]*\<[\s]*([^\s\>]*)[\s]*\>/\<$1\>/g
```

Data (d):

```
#include  <a.h>  // 2 spaces after e
```

output (o):

```
#include <a.h>  // 1 space is still there
```

Expected output is:

```
#include<a.h>  // no space after include
```

Comment: tip: `[\s]` is pointless. `[]` is for grouping MULTIPLE characters into a single match point. `[\s]*` is functionally identical to `\s*`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The condition `(?<!\#include)` is true as soon as you've passed the first of the two spaces, therefore the match starts there.

```
#include  <a.h>
         ^^^^^^- matched by your regex.
```

That means the space is not removed by your replace operation.

If you use a [positive lookbehind assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) instead, you get the desired result:

```
s/(?<=#include)\s*<\s*([^\s>]*)\s*>/<$1>/g;
```

which can be rewritten to use the [more efficient `\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex):

```
s/#include\K\s*<\s*([^\s>]*)\s*>/<$1>/g;
```

Comment: Or no lookbehind at all, like `s/(#include)\s*<\s*([^\s>]*)\s*>/$1<$2>/g`

Comment: I wanted to know why first space after #include is not the part of regex match.

Comment: @user1414235 Yes, and Tim told you, so what's the problem?

Comment: @user1414235 Because you've used a *negative*  lookbehind assertion, which prevented a match starting point at this position.

Answer (score 2):

`?<!\#include)[\s]` is a space that is not directly preceded by `#include`. The first space in `#include  <a.h>` is directly preceded by `#include`, so it isn't matched. The second one isn't (it's preceded by the other space), so that's where the match starts.

Answer (score 0):

As an aside comment, you can use this pattern which doesn't use the lookbehind:

```
s/(?:#include\K|\G)(?:\s+|(<|[^\s><]+))/$1/g
```

pattern details:

```
(?:              # open a non capturing group
    #include\K   # match "#include" and reset it from the match result
  |              # OR
    \G           # a contiguous match
)                # close the non capturing group
(?:          
    \s+          # white characters (spaces or tabs here) 
  |              # OR
    (            # capturing group
        <
      |
        [^\s><]+ # content inside brackets except spaces (and brackets)
    )
)
```

The search stop at the closing bracket since it is not describe in the pattern and since there is no more contiguous matches until the next `#include`.