# Regex: Matching 4-Digits within words

Tags: regex, perl

I have a body of text I'm looking to pull repeat sets of 4-digit numbers out from.

For Example:

> The first is 1234 2) The Second is 2098 3) The Third is 3213

Now I know i'm able to get the first set of digits out by simply using:

```
    /\d{4}/
```

...returning 1234

But how do I match the second set of digits, or the third, and so on...?

edit: How do i return 2098, or 3213

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Hi Rohit. I'm using Perl. My mistake, I assumed all Regex was the same.

Comment: And for the record, there are several 'dialects' of regular expressions, each with its own set of supported features. For instance, RegExp in JavaScript does not support negative look-behinds which are supported by Perl-style regexps.

Comment: Here's an idea. If you want to match the second "4 digits". You first match the first digits `\d{4}`. You then match everything ungreedy and match another 4 digits. `\d{4}.*?\d{4}`. The problem now is that you have a weird match (4 digits+random data+4 digits). To solve this, you may use the `\K` modifier, it "forget's" everything what's already matched,it's a powerfull replacement for "unlimited lookbehinds".So the final expression would look like `\d{4}.*?\K\d{4}`.You should get the second 4 digits. Now let's just hope your system is based on [Perl 5.10+](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13542950)

Comment: [See the expression in action when it's supported !!!](http://regex101.com/r/zH5kO0)

Comment: Upvotes for HamZa! Thank you, works a charm. How do I progress to the third, fourth and so on?

Comment: @Andy'Drew'Dodd Please don't forget to "ping" by using "@" otherwise I won't notice. Anyways, you should be using `\d{4}.*?\K\d{4}` for the second, `\d{4}.*?\d{4}.*?\K\d{4}` for the third and `\d{4}.*?\d{4}.*?\d{4}.*?\K\d{4}` for the forth and so on ...

Comment: @HamZa wow, interesting service! Which regexs it supports?

Comment: @loldop That's based on PCRE PHP, but I've got a lot of other services for other languages :P For example this [one](http://www.rexv.org/) it supports PHP PCRE, Perl PCRE, Python, JS ...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You don't appear to have a proper answer to your question yet.

The solution is to use the `/g` modifier on your regex. In list context it will find *all* of the numbers in your string at once, like this

```
my $str = 'The first is 1234 2) The Second is 2098 3) The Third is 3213';

my @numbers = $str =~ /\b \d{4} \b/gx;

print "@numbers\n";
```

**output**

```
1234 2098 3213
```

Or you can iterate through them, using scalar context in a `while` loop, like this

```
while ($str =~ /\b (\d{4}) \b/gx) {
  my $number = $1;
  print $number, "\n";
}
```

**output**

```
1234
2098
3213
```

I have added the `\b` patterns to the regex so that it only matches whole four-digit numbers and doesn't, for example, find `1234` in `1234567`. The `/x` modifier just allows me to add spaces so that the pattern is more intelligible.

Answer (score 1):

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html for discussion on the use of the 'g' modifier which will cause your regular expression to match ALL occurrances of its pattern, not just the first.

Comment: I am using a system that only accepts a regular expression as part of a function, it takes only the first match and doesn't allow me to use modifiers like 'g'.  I would be looking for a syntax that would say "give me the 2nd match of \d{4}\. Not sure if I'm making sense.

Comment: What does the documentation of the function you're using say about matching multiple copies of a pattern?  What is the function?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a pattern that finds the `$n`'th 4-digit group, this seems to work:

```
$pat = "^(?:.*?\\b(\\d{4})\\b){$n}";
if ($s =~ /$pat/) {
   print "Found $1\n";
} else {
   print "Not found\n";
}
```

I did this by building a string pattern because I couldn't get a variable interpolated into a quantifier `{$n}`.

This pattern finds 4-digit groups that are on word boundaries (the `\b` tests); I don't know if that meets your requirements.  The pattern uses `.*?` to ensure that as few characters as possible are matched between each four-digit group.  The pattern is matched `$n` times, and the capture group `$1` is set to whatever it was in the last iteration, i.e. the `$n`'th one.

EDIT: When I just tried it again, it seemed to interpolate `$n` in a quantifier just fine.  I don't know what I did differently that it didn't work last time.  So maybe this will work:

```
if ($s =~ /^(?:.*?\b(\d{4}\b){$n}/) { ...
```

If not, see amon's comment about `qr//`.

Comment: Ah, the dreaded double backslash. Protip: Use regex quotes `qr//`. Then: `qr/^(?: .*? \b(\d{4})\b ){$n}/x`

Answer (score 0):

If the regex is only matched once, then match all three in one regex and extract them using matched groups:

```
^.*\b(\d{4})\b.*\b(\d{4})\b.*\b(\d{4})\b.*$
```

The three 4-digit numbers will be captured in group 1. 2 and 3.

Comment: I think this will cause problems with the OP's example because the source contains "1)" and "2)", and that's going to fail the `\D+` test.

Comment: Yes, that should be better.  `\b` is the approach others and I were taking, but if the OP wants to extract 1234 out of ANumber1234InTheMiddleOfAWord then we'd need something different.  We don't really know his exact requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Ajb's answer with "gx" is the best. If you know you will have three numbers, this straighforward line does the trick:

```
my $str = 'The first is 1234 2) The Second is 2098 3) The Third is 3213';
my ($num1, $num2, $num3) = $str =~ /\b \d{4} \b/gx;
print "$num1, $num2, $num3\n";
```