# Regular expression to match specific variations of function

Tags: objective-c, regex, cocoa, nsregularexpression

I am trying to construct a regular expression to find the text of the following variations.

```
NSLocalizedString(@"TEXT")
NSLocalizedStringFromTable(@"TEXT")
NSLocalizedStringWithDefaultValue(@"TEXT")
...
```

The goal is to extract `TEXT`. I have been able to construct a regex for each individual function or macro, e.g., `(?<=NSLocalizedString)\(@"(.*?)"`. However, I am looking for a solution that does the job no matter what the name of the function as long as it starts with `NSLocalizedString`.

I assumed it was as simple as `(?<=NSLocalizedString\w+)\(@"(.*?)"`, but that does't seem to do the trick.

Comment: Don't bother with assertions. Just use your regex this way - `NSLocalizedString\w+\(@"(.*?)"` and read the result in capture group 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How about this one?

```
/NSLocalizedString\w*\(@"(.*)"\)/
```

Explanation:

```
  NSLocalizedString        'NSLocalizedString'
  \w+                      word characters (a-z, A-Z, 0-9, _) (0 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
  \(                       '('
  @"                       '@"'
  (                        group and capture to \1:
    .*                       any character except \n (0 or more times
                             (matching the most amount possible))
  )                        end of \1
  "                        '"'
  \)                       ')'
```

Comment: Since this regex doesn't use a lookbehind assertion, it selects the entire function/macro. The goal is to only extract `TEXT`.

Comment: TEXT is captured in the first group.

Answer (score 1):

The only reason your regex doesn't work is because the regex engine doesn't support variable length lookbehinds. The `(?<=NSLocalizedString\w+)` is variable length so can't be used.

Firstly it needs to be \w* not \w+, to allow your first example string to match.

If you move the `\w*` outside the lookbehind `(?<=NSLocalizedString)\w*` it will work just fine.

Alternatively, since you have to use a capturing group to grab the text value anyway, theres no need for the lookbehind at all. Change the `(?<=` to a `(?:` and it becomes a non-capturing group (which can be variable length), and then just grab your text value from group 1.

Your attempt was:

```
(?<=NSLocalizedString\w+)\(@"(.*?)"
```

Both of these minor changes should make it work:

```
(?<=NSLocalizedString)\w*\(@"(.*?)"

(?:NSLocalizedString\w*)\(@"(.*?)"
```

---

**The following is actually not supported in Objective-C:**

The solution that will extract exactly `TEXT` without using any groups is:

```
NSLocalizedString\w*\(@"\K[^"]*
```

It avoids the need to use a negative lookbehind (which can't be used for reasons I explain below) by using the `\K` modifier, which chops off anything before it from the match.

Comment: just updated to include what I think will be your ideal solution (matches exactly `TEXT` without using any groups - as you were originally trying to do)

Comment: Your solution is indeed ideal, but the `\K` modifier is not supported in Objective-C (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex). The alternatives you suggested do indeed work. The gotcha was indeed that lookbehind/lookahead assertions cannot have a variable length as you pointed out.