# Why is this regex lookbehind not following the left priority in an alternation?

Tags: c#, regex

Say input is `String1OptionalString2WhatWeWant`

Another kind of input is `String1WhatWeWant`

So I want to match `WhatWeWant` part, and first part should go to prefix.

However I cant seem to get this result.

Following regex doesn't produce desired effect

```
(?<=string1optionalstring2|string1)\w+
```

It still matches optionalstring2 while I don't what that.
I assumed that it would prefer left full match ..

Comment: What about this `([^(String1OptionalString2)|String1]\w+)`?

Comment: @RahilWazir not working I believe (just tested)

Comment: Have you tested with case insensitive modifier?

Comment: case sensitivity is not the issue here, its smth about engine general approach towards optional parts here which i dont quite catch

Comment: What language, tool, IDE are you using regex in?

Comment: Added C# language reference to question. The tool I am using is "Expresso"

Comment: @RahilWazir, `[^(xy)|z]` is a negated character class.  It matches **one character**, as long as that character is not `(`, `x`, `y`, `)`, `|`, or `z`.  In other words, you're completely on the wrong track.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `String1` is always present? Then:

```
(?:String1)(?:OptionalString2)?\w+
```

Comment: String1 is always present, but this doesn't work when I run it in test environment.. does it work for you or you assume it will?

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: so what's the environment? And which language are you using?

Comment: well i kinda asked first, does it work for you? that would be enough so I start to investigate why it doesn't for me. Language is C#, im using Expresso program to test out regexes if ur curious.

Comment: @ValentinKuzub: yes it should works in [Javascript](http://www.regexr.com/38lin) and [Ruby](http://rubular.com/r/mIqXghFgpT)

Comment: oki, cool I'll investigate. Do you have an idea with prefix though? Why doesn't it work?

Comment: If you want to extract the final part (what's matched by `\w+`), you should put it in a capturing group: `(\w+)`.

Comment: Marked as answer, but I still wonder how to make version with prefix work.

Answer (score 0):

**What happened**

To understand why the lookbehind behave in a seemingly incoherent way, remember that the regex engine goes from left to right and returns the first match it finds.

Let's look at the steps it takes to match `(?<=ab|a)\w+` on `abc`:

- the engine starts at `a`. There isn't anything before, so the lookbehind fails
- transmission kicks in, the engine is now considering a match starting from `b`
- the lookbehind tries the first item of the alternation (`ab`) which fails
- ... but the second item (`a`) matches
- `\w+` matches the rest of the string

The overall match is therefore `bc`, and the regex engine hasn't broken any of its rule in the process.

**How to fix it**

If C# supported the `\K` escape sequence, you could just use the greediness of `?` to do the work for you ([demo here](http://regex101.com/r/lY0jL2/1)):

```
string1(?:optionalstring2)?\K\w+
```

However, this (sadly) [isn't the case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex). It therefore seems that you are stuck with using a capturing group:

```
string1(?:optionalstring2)?(\w+)
```