# regular expression capture nth match

Tags: regex

Is there any way to, using regular expression, return the nth occurrence? I did search the forums and only found solution that goes beyond regular expression itself (i.e. needs support from the programming language).

Example:
Regex:

```
(?:\$(\d+(?:,\d{3})*\.\d{2}))
```

Input:

```
    thiscanbeanything$25.74thiscanbesomethingelse
alsowithnewlines$533.63thisonetoo$54.32plusthis$62.42thisneverends
```

I'd need to extract the first one (which is 25.74). Later on I might need to extract the third one (which is 54.32).

My regex is currently matching all occurrences. I could retrieve the nth element after matches but my question is: is it possible to do it via regular expression only (i.e. the regular expression will return only the nth element I want)?

Thanks!

Comment: It can be done with `^P{n-1}(P)` approach (where `P` is what you're trying to match. But it'll damage your code readability. I think you're already using good implementation.

Comment: This also depends on what language you're using, but if the engine you're using fully supports lookbehind, that would be useful. Essentially you match your regex, but preceded by X other matches of it.

Comment: @KendallFrey Not working: `(?si)(?:(?<=\$[\d.]+){1})(\$[\d.]+)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

for nth match use this pattern `(?:.*?\$[0-9.]+){XX}.*?(\$[0-9.]+)`
where `XX = n-1`

[Example for 3rd match](http://regex101.com/r/aD4zC1)

Comment: It wasn't obvious to me that the example linked to was missing a number in the curly braces. Also, it seems that it will work with {n} in the curly braces, not {n-1}. Example: https://regex101.com/r/uE0vM5/2

Comment: But this highlights up to and including the nth element, how do you return the contents of only group 1?

Comment: You don't need the capture group if [the regex engine supports `\K`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex): `(?:.*?\$[0-9.]+){XX}.*?\K\$[0-9.]+`. `\K` resets the starting point of the reported match to the current position in the string and discards all characters previously matched from the reported match.