# Match & Replace every "Second" occurrence of ", in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, str-replace

I want to replace every second occurrence of ", (DoubleQuote comma) with "." (Dot)

E.g.

"With all my will, but much against my heart",
"We two now part",
"My Very Dear",
"Our solace is, the sad road lies so clear",

Should be:

```
  "With all my will, but much against my heart",
  "We two now part.
  "My Very Dear",
  "Our solace is, the sad road lies so clear.
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression capture nth match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555593/regular-expression-capture-nth-match)

Comment: Can you include the code that you have tried to resolve inquiry at Question?

Answer (score 4):

Try using `split` followed by `reduce` as shown below

**Demo**

```js
var input = `"With all my will, but much against my heart",
  "We two now part",
  "My Very Dear",
  "Our solace is, the sad road lies so clear",`
console.log( input.split( /",/ ).reduce( (a,b, i) => i %2 == 0 ? a + "\"," + b : a + "." + b ) );

console.log("It does the trick but it starts from the first line!");
```