# Hiveql - how to keep only digits and spaces in string

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

To be more specific, if the original string column is like

1. 'AAA 123 BBB 456'
2. 'CCC 234 DDD EEE 678'
3. 'FFFFF 7280 ZZZ 123 DDD'

what I need eventually is the first cluster of numbers only, like

1. '123'
2. '234'
3. '7280'

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `regexp_extract` function:

```
select regexp_extract('AAA 123 BBB 456','[0-9]+',0) - digit one or more times
```

returns `123`

Comment: Thanks. It works perfectly. My understanding is that the final zero input is a group index, not a match index, so if there are multiple matches in a string, regexp_extract will always return the first one. Am I right?

Comment: @pingboing Right, this is a regex group index, not a match index

Comment: Is there an easy way to return other matches (say, the 2nd match) whenever there are multiple?

Comment: You need to write more complex regex. Like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/23556649/2700344

Comment: appreciate your help