# RegEx Pattern - how to extract the N element from a line?

Tags: regex, uipath

I try to create a pattern to extract some values from a line but without success. May I kindly ask you to give some help?

I would like to extract values from a line like this (just an easy example):

```
502,42 421,421.421 421421,421.55 551
[0-9,.]+
```

The problem is that I would like to assign each and every value to a different variable.

How should I do that?

Comment: `^(?:\d+[,. ]){N-1}(\d+)`? (Where `N` is the position of the element) See: https://regex101.com/r/I4mEzR/1

Comment: Dear Ahmed, Thank you for your answer in this regard. I have checked your solution but the goal would be to "split" the values on each Space \s, then I would have 4 different values and with the {N of element}- i can assign the value to a variable one by one by changing the N. is it possible? thanks, agian!

Comment: Are you using .NET? If so, why don't you use the [`Split()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.split) method instead of regex? Anyway, with regex, you can do something like `^(?:[0-9,.]+\s){N-1}([0-9,.]+)` and your Nth element will be in the first capturing group. See: https://regex101.com/r/WVkcrH/1 Or you can use `^(?:[0-9,.]+\s){2}\K[0-9,.]+` if your regex flavor supports `\K`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [regular expression capture nth match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555593/regular-expression-capture-nth-match)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you tagged this with UiPath, here's one approach. Create one variable holding your regex, and up to n variables for each match. Add an `Invoke Code` activity. Map input and output arguments to your variables (in my case there's one input - the regex, and two outputs).

[image: regex in uipath]

Change the code as required. The pattern might become another input argument.

```
Dim matches As MatchCollection = Regex.Matches(in_RegEx, "\d")
out_part0 = matches(0).Value
out_part1 = matches(1).Value
```

Assuming you provided `1 2 3 4` as input and `\d` as the pattern, `part0 == 1` and `part1 == 2`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm very glad to see your comments, thank you for your cooperation in this regard. I also found a solution for my "problem":

- Read PDF Text (or other source...)
- Matches activity - with the pattern
- Assign activity (as many as needed - for me the Variable type is Double) = Double.Parse((Matches(0).Groups(2).value).ToString.Replace(".","").Replace(",",".").Trim)
- Write line (just for checking the results)

If you create a pattern, the only thing which should be changed is the number of the .Groups(**N**) within the Assign activity.

neptun