# Search and replace a word in a specific place

Tags: javascript, regex

I can't solve one problem.

There is a string in which in some places there are hex codes, codes can be many. 
I need to write a function that can return a string with changed codes. 
What was I trying to do:

```js
function test(i,color){
 let str = "Lorem ipsum #1385ff dolor sit amet, #1385ff consectetur adipisicing #1385ff  elit. #333 Neque , est, voluptatum,#333";
 str = str.replace(str.match(/#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3}/gi)[i],color) 
 return str
}
console.log(test(2,"#000"))
```

What I expected to get:

`Lorem ipsum #1385ff dolor sit amet, #1385ff consectetur adipisicing #000 elit. #1385ff Neque quibusdam, est, voluptatum,#333333 aperia`

What I got:

`Lorem ipsum #000 dolor sit amet, #1385ff consectetur adipisicing #1385ff  elit. #1385ff Neque , est, voluptatum,#333333`

I will be very grateful for your help :)

Comment: And what are the rules for the replacement(s) ?

Comment: Hex codes in a string are arranged in a certain sequence, but they can have completely different values or be the same. The function must be able to change hex code with a specific index, which is passed through parameters.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23555593/regular-expression-capture-nth-match)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a replacer function to count up the position you want to replace.

```js
function test(i,color){
 let str = "Lorem ipsum #1385ff dolor sit amet, #1385ff consectetur adipisicing #1385ff  elit. #333 Neque , est, voluptatum,#333";
  var j = 0;
 str = str.replace(/#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3}/gi,function(x){return j++!==i? x : color}) 
 return str
}
console.log(test(2,"#000"))
```

Another version without using replacer function.  Builds a new RegExp each time that matches pattern `i` times, captures all that text, reinserts that text, and replaces the `i`th match with `color`

```js
function test(i,color){
 let str = "Lorem ipsum #1385ff dolor sit amet, #1385ff consectetur adipisicing #1385ff  elit. #333 Neque , est, voluptatum,#333";
 str = str.replace(new RegExp(`((?:.*?#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3}){${i}}.*?)(?:#[0-9a-f]{6}|#[0-9a-f]{3})`,'i'),`$1${color}`) 
 return str
}
console.log(test(2,"#000"))
```

Comment: Yes, thank you! I didn't care if I used regexp or not. The function does what me needs. Thank you again)