# Grab word after the match with regex

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to get the word with the following:

```
$string = 'code 10OFF75 +EXTRA';
$regex  = '/(?<=code)\s\w+/';
```

Output (tried at rubular.com):

```
10OFF75
```

I want to skip the special character with the word `code`. Say, I have the string `code: | code- | code:-` then how do I grab the next word?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try to use the `\K` feature that removes all on the left from match result:

```
/code\W+\K\w+/
```

Comment: Oh surprisingly awesome, can you suggest some resources to learn more about the power of regex.

Comment: @jogesh_pi: You can take a look at this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean , you can find informations in the PHP manual, http://pcre.org/pcre.txt , http://rexegg.com , http://regular-expressions.info

Comment: Nice, +1. Added variations for the day he ends up in C# or JS. :)

Comment: +1 never heard of `\K`. Sadly it only works with PCRE :s

Comment: @naomik: You can use it with Ruby2 too.

Comment: `grep -P` supports `\K` too, last I checked.

Answer (score 2):

What [Casimir said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24217037/1438393) (recommended for PCRE)... and other options for the road, in case you find yourself [other languages that don't have `\K` support](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/1438393) some day:

**With lookbehind**

```
(?<=code\W+)\w+
```

This will work in .NET and Python's regex module, which have infinite-width lookbehind.

**With capturing groups**

```
code\W+(\w+)
```

The parentheses capture the match to group 1. This works in JavaScript (which doesn't support lookbehind) and most other Perl-style engines.

Comment: `(?<=...)` is a positive lookbehind, `(?<!...)` is a negative lookbehind.

Comment: Coincidentally, JavaScript's regexp flavor supports neither `\K` nor lookbehinds **^.^**

Comment: @naomik: yes, the most portable way is the capture group.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Er... negative-negative lookbehind. :) Thanks for spotting the typo!