# How to find "explicit int access in arrays in my source code" via regex?

Tags: regex, visual-studio-2010

How can I find all my array usages that have an explicit integer as index?

**Example:**

```
const int CON = 42;
int[] arr = new int[100];
arr[34] = 12;
arr[CON] = 13;

// need to find: [100], [34]
// not         : [], [CON]
```

---

This seems to work with C# Regex and Replace but not in VS 2010 search:

```
\[\d+\]
```

*(I'm sure I formulated the title awkwardly or something. Sorry.)*

Comment: By using a proper parser. A simple example where it could fail is commented lines.

Comment: `^(?<!\/).*?\K(\[\d+\])(?=.*?;)` will work in C# and will not return anything commented out with a "/".

Comment: @jbarker2160 since when does C# support `\K`? ([Looking at this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex/13543042#13543042))

Comment: @jbarker2160 `"You forgot [strings]"`.

Comment: @HamZa, I'm not sure, but that's where I tested it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a table of regex patterns used in Visual Studio on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k3te2cs.aspx. In VS2010 and before, you use `:d` to match digits:

```
\[:d+\]
```

Comment: That's it! Of course OP is in for false positives, such as array declarations with `int` literals as dimensions, but that is about as far as you can go without an actual parser.

Comment: Thanks! Works. Exactly what I wanted.