# matching character when preceded by specific string

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to find characters when preceded with exact string but not the preceding string. how to do that?

I have the string

```
+1545464454<+440545545454<+210544455454<+75455454545
```

the above string are phone numbers with international prefix, but some of them have 0 between prefix and number and I need to take it out.

I have `/(\+4|\+44|\+7 ... allprefixes here...)0/g` but this selects the prefix as well and I need to select only `0`

I's in the javascript

Comment: which language are you using?

Comment: did you want to remove those zero's? What's your expected output?

Comment: Use `\K` before `0`. [See which languages/tools support it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex).

Comment: updated - it's javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're almost close to that. Just use Capturing groups and replace function  like below. Most languages support capturing groups.

```
/(\+(?:4|44|7 ... allprefixes here without `+`...))0/g
```

REplacement string:

```
$1
```

or `\1`

If you're on PHP, `\K` should work. `\K` discards previously matched characters from printing at the final.

```
'~\+(?:4|44|7)\K0~g'
```

**In javascript.**

```
> var str = "+1545464454<+440545545454<+210544455454<+75455454545"
> str.replace(/(\+(?:44|21|7|4))0/g, "$1")
'+1545464454<+44545545454<+21544455454<+75455454545'
```

Answer (score 2):

If your language supports lookbehinds, you can use it as used in the following regex

```
/(?<=\+(4|44|7))0/g
```

Javascript doesn't support it. So you'll need to use something like this

```
str.replace(/(\+(4|44|7))0/, "$1");
```

Comment: PCRE supports *fixed* lookbehinds. This one isn't fixed. This solution only works in a really few languages/tools. One of them is .net

Comment: op wants to select only `0`'s which are next to prefixes.

Comment: @HamZa ah! Added another solution. Thanks