# How to parse between !!! and ??? using regex

Tags: regex, string, parsing, literals, nsregularexpression

I have a string of text like the following:

> Image 56 ::: Beach, Summer, Sun **!!!** John Smith **???**

I'd like to extract just **John Smith**

Ive tried `(?s)(?<=\!\!\!).+?(?=\?\?\?})`

and `(\!\!\!)(?:[^])*?(\?\?\?)`
 but the first one doesn't work, and the second one gives the result `!!! John Smith ???` not just John Smith. Can you offer some help? Thank you

Comment: Not _every_ job requires a hammer :-) Have you thought of perhaps simply using string functions to locate and extract the data? It's likely to be far more readable.

Comment: No idea what a hammer is, nor what you mean :) Sorry I'm just starting to lerrn regex tonight. Will look into those terms though, cheers

Comment: a hammer is a tool used for banging in nails, it's not some new sort of IT thing :-) The saying I'm referring to is "if the only tool you have is a hammer, every problem looks like a nail". And what I mean is that, maybe, regex is not the right tool for this job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a capturing group with a negated character class.

```
!!!\s*([^?]+?)\s*\?{3}
```

To display the match result you need to reference the first group index.

#### [Live Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zZ9iC5/1)

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, see: http://regexr.com/3a717. It's grabbing the !!! and ??? too, not just John Smith

Comment: You are correct, and awarded first prize! Thank you kindly

Answer (score 1):

There's a stray `}` character in your first pattern. Remove that and it'll work.

Comment: yeah but there are still whitespaces to be trimmed

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, but perhaps I'm just slow. Either way, thanks for the input

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
!!!\s+\K.*?(?=\s+\?{3})
```

#### Check https://regex101.com/r/uF0gV8/1 and [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex)

#### EXPLANATIONS:

```
NODE                     EXPLANATION
----------------------------------------------------------------------
(?-imsx:                 group, but do not capture (case-sensitive)
                         (with ^ and $ matching normally) (with . not
                         matching \n) (matching whitespace and #
                         normally):
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  !!!                      '!!!'
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or
                           more times (matching the most amount
                           possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  \K                       restart the match
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  .*?                      any character except \n (0 or more times
                           (matching the least amount possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?=                      look ahead to see if there is:
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s+                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
----------------------------------------------------------------------
    \?{3}                    '?' (3 times)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of look-ahead
----------------------------------------------------------------------
)                        end of grouping
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
!!!\s*\K[^\n\r?]+?(?=\s*\?\?\?)
```

Comment: this also grabs the whitespaces surrounding the string