# Perl parsing JavaScript file regex, to catch quotes only at the beginning and end of the returned string

Tags: regex, perl

I'm just starting to learn Perl. I need to parse JavaScript file. I came up with the following subroutine, to do it:

```
sub __settings {
    my ($_s) = @_;
    my $f = $config_directory . "/authentic-theme/settings.js";
    if ( -r $f ) {
        for (
            split(
                '\n',
                $s = do {
                    local $/ = undef;
                    open my $fh, "<", $f;
                    <$fh>;
                    }
            )
            )
        {
            if ( index( $_, '//' ) == -1
                && ( my @m = $_ =~ /(?:$_s\s*=\s*(.*))/g ) )
            {
                my $m = join( '\n', @m );
                $m =~ s/[\'\;]//g;
                return $m;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have the following regex, that removes `'` and `;` from the string:

`s/[\'\;]//g;`

It works alright *but* if there is a mentioned chars (`'` and `;`) in string - then they are also removed. This is undesirable and that's where I stuck as it gets a bit more complicated for me and I'm not sure how to change the *regex* above correctly to only:

1. Remove only first `'` in string
2. Remove only last `'` in string
3. Remove ont last `;` in string if exists

Any help, please?

Comment: matching expression is: 1. `^[^']*(')` 2. `(')[^']*$` 3.`;$` but I'm not familiar with Perl syntax to help further, I imagine for # 1 & # 2 this will cause the whole match to be removed, maybe you can find something that removes only the matched group 1, for # 3 it will work.

Comment: Single-character identifiers make your code much more difficult to follow

Comment: That is annoying Sublie Text formater for Perl. Any other you could recommend please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Remove only first ' in string
>
> Remove only last ' in string

```
^[^']*\K'|'(?=[^']*$)
```

Try this .See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/8

> Remove ont last ; in string if exists

```
;(?=[^;]*$)
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/9

All three in one

```
^[^']*\K'|'(?=[^']*$)|;(?=[^;]*$)
```

[See Here](https://regex101.com/r/oF9hR9/10)

Comment: ..and if I would want to replace later in string `'` with `\'` in case it's not already `\'`. This one doesn't work for me: `s/'/\'/g`?

Comment: No. This one works `s/\'/\\'/g` but it replaces those at the beginning and at the end.

Comment: `a = 'This is the test's string';`. Now on the output I need the final regex that would replace all unescaped `'` with `\'` but not at the beginning or end..

Comment: This is totally awesome! :) Thanks, pal!

Comment: One remark: already escaped quotes will also get escaped: https://regex101.com/r/yW3oJ9/1.

Comment: @stribizhev cool!! ..but they are pre-processed already and there should be no such cases but better safe than sorry! :)

Comment: @vks awesome fix, really! :D

Comment: Do you know how to make this one `s/^[^']*'(*SKIP)(*F)|'[^']*$(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<!\\)'/\\'/gim` work on older versions of Perl, like 5.8? It fails on version < 5.10. I think `(SKIP)` part or `(*F)` makes it fail.

Comment: Returned error in Perl 5.8.8 is `Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/^[^']'( <-- HERE SKIP)(F)|'[^']$(SKIP)(F)|(?<!\)'/`

Comment: Could you please try, cause I'm not fluent with Regex on this level? There are just few groups.

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev i would suggest you put up a new question...as this is complex and would need advanced features of perl :)

Comment: ok! php :) It was Perl really.. But it's irrelevant I think.. I will do, in case I don't figure this out! Thanks, pal!

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev ahh sry....... actually it would require conditional replace....m a python guy...so i know in python...some perl guy can definitly do it.......do put up a question in case you dont find a solution :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following to match:

```
^'|';?$|;$
```

And replace with `''` (empty string)

See [DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/tA9dT2/2)

Comment: It seems that last `;` is not removed properly.

Comment: You can use `(?<!\\)'` for matching `'` which are not `\'` and replace with `\'` ..

Answer (score 2):

You can use this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
$str = "'string; 'inside' another;"; 
$str =~ s/^'|'?;?$//g;
print $str;
```

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/9gQkcZ)

The main idea is to use anchors: `^` beginning of string, `$` end of string and `;?` matches the ";" symbol at the end only if it is present (`?` quantifier is making the pattern preceding it optional).
**EDIT**: Also, `;` will get removed even if there is no preceding `'`.

Comment: Thanks, I knew about those anchors. I just wasn't sure how to combine it all in one.

Comment: Ilya, you can just use [alternation operator](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) with 2 parts. Also, look-arounds (as used in another answer are resource-consuming. My suggestion does not use look-arounds.

Comment: Well, I tested it and it seems that last `;` is not removed properly. Спасибо!

Comment: I've updated the code. Now, it will remove the `;` even if there is no `'`.

Comment: Yes, true. Because _Boolean_ values in JavaScript  are now wrapped in `'`. That is cool! It seems to work the same way as _vks_'s example: `^[^']*\K'|'(?=[^']*$)|;(?=[^;]*$)`

Comment: Yes, it is true. There is one thing about `\K`: if you plan to migrate to another engine in future, it might stop working. My suggestion is more universal. See [\K regex support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex) for more details.

Comment: `\K` thing seems a bit difficult for me to understand at the moment! _vks_'s answer seems more universal though! I just need to work more on regex in general! Thank you again!

Comment: @karthikmanchala: Yeah, I tested, a tiny bit (like ~10 steps).

Comment: @stribizhev .. a tiny bit.. yes.. but i don think we can specify number of steps here.. because steps proportional to length of string.. take big string.. and tiny bit will be ~100 steps.. :)

Comment: @karthikmanchala: Anyway, it seems to me vks' solution is better than ours :)

Comment: @stribizhev .. no ours is better.. check it again.. :D

Comment: I agree that `^[^']*\K'|'(?=[^']*$)|;(?=[^;]*$)` will not always remove *final* `'`:  https://regex101.com/r/fU9qK4/1

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that your original code should look more like this. It is much more idiomatic Perl and I think more straightforward to follow

```
sub __settings {
    my ($_s) = @_;
    my $file = "$config_directory/authentic-theme/settings.js";
    return unless -r $file;

    open my $fh, '<', $file or die qq{Unable to open "$file" for input: $!};
    my @file = <$fh>;
    chomp @file;

    for ( @file ) {
        next if m{//};
        if ( my @matches = $_ =~ /(?:$_s\s*=\s*(.*))/g ) {
            my $matches = join "\n", @matches;
            $matches =~ tr/';//d;
            return $matches;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks and yes, I guess, but at the moment I'm doing Perl with my previous knowledge of other programming languages - interesting thing, that it works! :) I find your formatting easier to read! How can I format Perl in Sublime Text 3 like this?

Comment: @IliaRostovtsev: The main advantage is the meaningful variable names, the reduced nesting of blocks, and the additional whitespace. But the indentation can be achieved with `perltidy` which should have been included as part of your Perl installation