# Regex: How to leave out string + space before a domain or IP address?

Tags: python, regex

The following regex:

```
(?:X-)?Received: (?:by|from) ([^ \n]+)
```

will, for the following lines, match the text in bold:

**Received: from mail2.oknotify2.com** (mail2.oknotify2.com. [208.83.243.70]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03

**Received: by 10.66.156.198** with SMTP id wg6mr62843415pab.126.1433365924352;

**Received: from localhost** (localhost [127.0.0.1])

If I alter the text such that "Received by: " and "Received: from " are removed in each line, leaving me with:

```
from mail2.oknotify2.com (mail2.oknotify2.com. [208.83.243.70]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03

by 10.66.156.198 with SMTP id wg6mr62843415pab.126.1433365924352;

from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])
```

How do I update the regex then to just match the IP addresses or domains (e.g. mail.oknotify2.com, 10.66.156.198) in this text?

I can reduce it to `(?:by|from) ([^ \n]+)` and that will give me "from mail.oknotify2.com", "by 10.66.156.198" etc. But how do I go the last step and omit the "by " and "from ", leaving only the domain/IP address? The final regex should also, as the original, ignore subsequent domains/IPs per line where present e.g. mx.google.com in the first line.

Comment: I am not sure what you want: 2 regexps to match domains and IPs? [This regex](https://regex101.com/r/yC6rI0/1) is not what you are looking for?

Comment: @stribizhev Thanks for the suggested regex. It includes the trailing "by " and "from " in the matches though. What I'm looking for is to omit these, leaving just the domain or IP.

Comment: What regex flavor you are using? In [.NET, you can use variable width look-behind](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=(%3f%3c%3d%5e(%3f%3aby%7cfrom)%5cs*)%5cS%2b&i=from+mail2.oknotify2.com+(mail2.oknotify2.com.+%5b208.83.243.70%5d)+by+mx.google.com+with+ESMTP+id+dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03%0d%0a%0d%0aby+10.66.156.198+with+SMTP+id+wg6mr62843415pab.126.1433365924352%3b%0d%0a%0d%0afrom+localhost+(localhost+%5b127.0.0.1%5d)&o=m), in [PCRE, there is `\K`](https://regex101.com/r/yC6rI0/2).

Comment: @stribizhev odd, when I take your regex over to nregex.com and try it there, the only match returned is "from mail2.oknotify2.com". Yet when I run the generated Python code on regex101, I get exactly what I'm looking for: just the domains and IPs. The re.MULTILINE seems to be a factor, but what else explains the difference in behaviour? P.S. Thanks for the solution, and for making me aware of regex101.com

Comment: So, Python? I will post my answer for Python then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `re.MULTILINE` flag to enable multiline mode to enable matching some text at the start of a line with `^`. To get the necessary text, you will have to use a capturing group.

It is a pity that Python regex does not support `\K`, nor variable-width look-behind (with the native `re` library). However, a variable width look-behind is possible to use with the [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) external library.

Here is a sample code that you can use:

```
import re
p = re.compile(ur'^(?:by|from) (\S+)', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"from mail2.oknotify2.com (mail2.oknotify2.com. [208.83.243.70]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03\n\nby 10.66.156.198 with SMTP id wg6mr62843415pab.126.1433365924352;\n\nfrom localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])"
print [x.group(1) for x in re.finditer(p, test_str)]
```

Output of [a demo program](http://ideone.com/2SMZUJ):

```
[u'mail2.oknotify2.com', u'10.66.156.198', u'localhost']
```

Comment: Please check my answer. If there is anything unclear please let me know.

Answer (score 2):

You can use \K to discard previous matches:

```
(?:X-)?Received: (?:by|from) \K([\S]+)
```

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yC6rI0/4)

EDIT:

Like @James Newton  said, this however is not supported by all regex flavors, you can refer to this post to see if your engine supports it:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/3393095

EDIT 2:

Since you specified Python, just using the capturing groups and `re.findall` on your regex will do, like this:

```
>>> import re
>>> text = ("Received: from mail2.oknotify2.com (mail2.oknotify2.com. [208.83.243.70]) by mx.google.com with ESMTP id dp5si2596299pdb.170.2015.06.03.14.12.03\n"
... "Received: by 10.66.156.198 with SMTP id wg6mr62843415pab.126.1433365924352;\n"
... "Received: from localhost (localhost [127.0.0.1])")
>>> re.findall(r'(?:X-)?Received: (?:by|from) ([\S]+)', text)
['mail2.oknotify2.com', '10.66.156.198', 'localhost']
```

Comment: Caution: If this is for JavaScript then the \K will simply match uppercase K.

Comment: @JamesNewton Thanks. I'm only looking to match the domain name and IP themselves though, no leading characters. So if I pare back your regex thus: (?:by|from) \K([\S]+) this almost does the job, but it still matches the additional domain (mx.google.com) in line 1. How can we prevent this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm writing an answer because a comment does not allow for formatting, but the correct answer is given by @stribizhev.

@stribizhev proposed this regex:

```
^(?:by|from) (\S+)
```

The `?:` at the beginning of `(?:by|from)` makes it a non-capturing group. `(\S+)` is a capturing group. If you use `result = string.match(regex)`, and there is a match, then `result` will contain an array such as `["from mail2.oknotify2.com", "mail2.oknotify2.com"]`. The value of result[1] is the captured group.