# Replace specific part of a string

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm currently encountering a pickle in modifications of a document. Lets say for example, I have this chunk of text:

```
                "id": "EFM",
                "type": "Casual",
                "hasBeenAssigned": false,
                "hasRandomAssigned": false
            },
```

I currently have roughly 73 - 80 occourances of:

```
 "id" : "somethingdifferent",
```

Using a regular expression in notepad++, How can I select the entire string:

```
 "id" : "",
```

but only change the contents between the second set of quotes?

---

**Edit**

An oversight made me leave this information out:

```
"equipedOutfit": {
                    "id": "MkIV",
                    "type": "Outfit",
                    "hasBeenAssigned": false,
                    "hasRandonAssigned": false
                },
                "equipedWeapon": {
                    "id": "EFM",
                    "type": "Casual",
                    "hasBeenAssigned": false,
                    "hasRandonAssigned": false
                },
```

The selected text, looking for is:

```
 "id" : "EFM",
```

Comment: Only `EFM` needs to be replaced?

Comment: Are you meaning from `second set of quotes` as only for the `equipedWeapon.id` and to leave `equipedOutfit.id` unchanged or just the value of any `id`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex like this:

```
("id": ").*?"
```

With a replacement string:

```
$1whatever"
  ^^^^^^^^--- replace 'whatever' with whatever you want
```

**[Working demo](https://regex101.com/r/wF5lL2/2)**

[image]

**Update:** as you updated your question, I'm updating the answer. If you want only to replace `"id": "EFM"` then you have just to look for that text only and put the replacement string you want.

Comment: Whilst this works. I unfortunately left out some important information. Give me a second

Comment: @DarylGill I updated my answer. However, I don't see any regex you need to look for a simple string.

Answer (score 1):

```
"id":\s*"\K[^"]*
```

You can use `\K` here and replace by `whatever you want`.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/sS2dM8/29

EDIT:

If you want only `EFM` then use

```
"id"\s*:\s*"\KEFM(?=")
```

Comment: what does `\K` stand for in that regex?

Comment: @gion_13 `\K` will match and discard it from the final match.

Comment: Very informative... I come from a javascript background and it's the first time I've ever heard of this regex special character. Thanks!

Comment: @gion_13 `\K` is not there in `javascript`.Only `pcre`

Comment: Yes, I've noticed that and there seems to be a very short list of regex implementation that do support it:http://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/491075.  However, that answer lists *notepad++* in the not supporting `\K` list.

Comment: @gion_13 `notepad++` version 6 and above supports `\K`

Answer (score 1):

Find what: `("id"\s?:\s?").*(")`

Replace with: `\1somethingdifferent\2`

Options:
Regular expression, Wrap around

[image]