# Match only first occurrence of digit

Tags: regex, bash, grep, text-processing

After few hours of disappointed searching I can't figure this out.

I am piping to `grep` input, what I want to get is first occurrence of any digit.

**Example:**

```
nmcli --version
nmcli tool, version 1.1.93
```

**Pipe to grep with regex**

```
nmcli --version |grep -o '[[:digit:]]'
```

**Output:**

```
1
1
9
3
```

**What I want:**

```
1
```

Yeah there is a way to do that with another pipe, but is there "pure" single regex to do that?

Comment: @trincot did you bother to try that?  `^` matches the beginning of a string, not the first instance of the following pattern.

Comment: none of the digits are at the beginning of the string, @trincot.

Comment: `nmcli --version | awk -F '[ .]' '{print $4}'`?

Comment: A "pure regex" is a closed-form formula which expresses a set of strings. A pure regex doesn't search through text or extract text, etc; it answers the question "is this string in the set or not". All else is not a "pure regex".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
nmcli --version | grep -Po ' \K[[:digit:]]'
```

Output:

```
1
```

See: [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13542950/3776858)

Comment: Many thanks! I just have one question about it. Is regular expression metacharacter "pure" regex expression in the world? Maybe we can't do that another way, but I was hoping in something like '[[:digit:]]?' (? match 0 or 1 time). Is it possible, or this have to be done with special care of metacharacters?

Comment: If you're okay using `awk` (see other answer) instead of `grep`, we can do it in a more portable way. But, with `grep`, and without using `head -1`, this is probably the best way. Upvoting this when my vote limit resets in 2 hours :)

Answer (score 1):

Although you want to avoid another process, it seems simplest just to add a `head` to your existing command...

```
grep -o [[:digit:]] | head -n1
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "nmcli tool, version 1.1.93" |sed "s/[^0-9]//g" |cut -c1
1

echo "nmcli tool, version 1.1.93" |grep -o '[0-9]' |head -1
1
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be seen as a stream editing task: reduce that one line to the first digit. Basic regex register-based referencing achieves the task:

```
$ echo "junk 1.2.3.4" | sed -e 's/.* \([0-9]\).*/\1/'
1
```

Traditionally, Grep is best for searching for files and lines which match a pattern. This is why the grep solution requires the use of Perl regex; Perl regex has features that, in combination with `-o`, allow grep to escape "out of the box" and be used in ways it wasn't really intended: match X, but then output a substring of X. The solution is terse, but not portable to grep implementations that don't have PCRE.

Use `[0-9]` to match ASCII digits, by the way. The purpose of `[[:digit:]]` is to bring in locale-specific behavior: to be able to match digits other than just the ASCII 0x30 through 0x39.

It's fairly safe to say that `nmcli` isn't going to put outs its `--version` using, say, Devangari numerals, like १.२.३.४.

Answer (score -2):

You could use standard `awk` instead:

```
nmcli --version | awk 'match($0, /[[:digit:]]/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); exit}'
```

For example:

```
$ seq 11111 33333 | awk 'match($0, /[[:digit:]]/) {print substr($0, RSTART, RLENGTH); exit}'
1
```

Comment: `nmcli --version | grep -o -m1 '[[:digit:]]'` It's not working but with seq it is, also `awk` example print whole line...

Comment: your `m1` suggestion does not work.  Despite what the manual implies, this stops after the first *line* that matches, not after the first actual match.  It only worked with your `seq 7 10` example because `seq 7 10` returns 4 separate lines, with each number 7 to 10 on a different line.

Comment: @PaulL Everything should work properly now. I didn't test it with realistic input, sorry.