# Linux - grep to exclude all words in front searched pattern

Tags: linux, grep

For example, whey I type:

```
grep Eth test.sh
```

I will get

```
Summary: Ethernet settings tool for PCI ethernet cards
```

Say if I only need my searched pattern and exlucde all words ahead

```
Ethernet settings tool for PCI ethernet cards
```

How can I do this in grep?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With GNU grep:

```
grep -Po '\KEth.*' test.sh
```

Output:

```
Ethernet settings tool for PCI ethernet cards
```

Comment: Pure-code answers can usually be improved by explaining what you did.

Comment: @user3815726: See: [Support of \K in regex](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13542950/3776858) and `man grep`.

Comment: that should be part of the answer, and not a link in the comment.

Comment: It is deliberately here.