# Parsing text file in python

Tags: text-processing, python

So I am trying to python program that will extract the round trip time from a web server ping stored in a text file. So what I basically have is a text file with this:

```
    PING e11699.b.akamaiedge.net (104.100.153.112) 56(84) bytes of data.
    64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=1 ttl=60 time=17.2ms
    64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=2 ttl=60 time=12.6ms
    64 bytes from a104-100-153-112.deploy.static.akamaitechnologies.com (104.100.153.112): icmp_seq=3 ttl=60 time=11.7ms
    ... (a bunch more ping responses here)
    --- e11699.b.akamaiedge.net ping statistics ---
    86400 packets transmitted, 86377 received, 0% packet loss, time 86532481ms
    rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 6.281/18.045/1854.971/28.152 ms, pipe 2
```

I am very new to python and need help being able to use regex commands to extract only the times between "time=" and "ms"and send it to another text file to look like:

```
11.7
12.6
17.2
...
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5):

Since this seems to come from [ping](/questions/tagged/ping) command, you could use [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) like this :

```
grep -oP 'ttl=\d+\s+time=\K[\d\.]+' file
```

#### Output :

```
17.2
12.6
11.7
```

#### Note :

It's very simple to search SO or/and google to use this regex in *pure python*.

#### Hint :

[Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex)

#### Bonus

Because I still have to play with python :

(in a [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) shell) :

```
python2 <<< $'import re\nf = open("/tmp/file", "r")\nfor textline in f.readlines():\n\tmatches = re.finditer("ttl=\d+\s+time=([\d\.]+)ms", textline)\n\tresults = [float(match.group(1).strip()) for match in matches if len(match.group(1).strip())]\n\tif results:\n\t\tprint results[0]\nf.close()\n'
```

Comment: I would prefer having the python equivalent of grep

Comment: Now you have the _regex_, all what you need is to search google a bit to use it

Comment: I have been googling regex for a while and am getting stuck on its syntax rules

Comment: Added python for fun

Comment: @user192314 Next time, instead of cross posting, you can ask for clarification for things you might not understand. The answerer here has given a functional answer and a working Python solution with regex.

Comment: @GillesQuenot why do you use  here string and bunch of explicit new-lines ? Isn't it simpler to make a script or use `-c` like i did ?

Comment: Because I'm not a free coding service, and I try to get fun and a bit of search/interest from the OP ;)

Answer (score 1):

Since you asked for Python, here it is:

```
$ ping -c 4 8.8.8.8 | python -c 'import sys;[ sys.stdout.write(l.split("=")[-1]+"\n") for l in sys.stdin if "time=" in l]'            
10.5 ms

9.22 ms

9.37 ms

9.71 ms
```

Note, this has stdout buffering, so you may want to add `sys.stdout.flush()` . Feel free to convert this from one liner to a script

Answer (score 0):

You specified that your data is already in a text file. So asuming that your text file is called `data.txt`

```
#we will be using the regular expression library for this example
import re 

#open the "data.txt" (named data_file in a scope)
with open("data.txt") as data_file: 
    #read the text from the data_file into ping_data
    ping_data = data_file.read() 
    found_data = re.findall('time=(.*)ms', ping_data)

with open('found.txt', 'w') as found_file:
    for pattern in found_data:
        found_file.write(pattern+"\n")
```

This fill output a file called `found.txt` with the following:

```
17.2
12.6
11.7
```

In the example we just open your data.txt file. Then read the data form it. Then find all the occurrences of the regular expression pattern that will return the data you are looking for.

`time=(.*)ms` means *a string of any size between the letters `time=` and `ms`

Then after we have found the patern we simply write it to another file called `found.txt`, writing one line at a time until its complete.