# Notepad++ regex replace with captures from the same file

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a file with the following lines (condensed example, real file is 1.000+ lines):

```
...
type1.value1=60  <-- replace 60 with 72 from line 5
type1.value2=15  <-- replace 15 with 14 from line 6
type2.value1=50  <-- replace 50 with 72 from line 5
type2.value2=18  <-- replace 18 with 14 from line 6
type3.value1=72  
type3.value2=14
...
```

I want to replace all values from type(x) with the values from type3. There are many type/value combinations, so i would like to avoid handwork. Also, i have to do this really often.

Is that possible with Notepad++ Regex find/replace?

The matching expression is the following, where the first group should stay the same and the second should be replaced by the result of yet anoter regex.

```
^type1.([\w]+)=([\S]+)
```

Comment: You can use FIND/REPLACE option in Notepad++

Comment: How does that automatically find the "72" in line 3? As i mentioned, i have a LOT of entries and the example is just a small snippet. There are over 200 cases and 1000+ lines in the file.

Comment: Is the line with the desired value always 2 lines later?

Comment: @Harper your question is little bit confusing. can you provide some example? as you said you want to replace "FzgF80.RxDBGrid1.Item15.Width=60" with "FzgF84.RxDBGrid1.Item15.Width=72 " and now you want to replace 72 with??? please be more clear.

Comment: @Harper DOES "FzgF80.RxDBGrid1.Item15.Width=60" always has "60" as initial value?

Comment: No it does not. The values are unknown, as well as the line positions. I will simplify the example above to make it clearer.

Comment: @bobblebubble Does notepad++ support `\K` ?

Comment: @UnbearableLightness [yes, it does](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/5527985)

Comment: Neat, then post your comment as an answer ;)

Comment: Tanks for the suggestion, i definetly learned something from that. Unfortunately i dont know the distance between the entries.

Comment: If that `valueX` in type `N` should be replaced with the same `valueX` in type `3` then see the live demo here https://regex101.com/r/50QXfc/1

Comment: Awesome. Thank you. If you post it as an answer i will accept it.

Comment: OK, it seems my notepad++ does not support \K. I could modify the regex using capturing groups to the following: 

Regex: (FzgF(?!84\.)\d{2})\.(\S+)=\S+(?=[\s\S]*?FzgF84\.\2=(\S+))

Substitution: \1.\2=\3

Comment: @Harper or you update your np++

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Regex:

```
type(?!3\.)\d+\.value(\d+)=\K\d+(?=[\s\S]*?type3\.value\1=(\d+))
```

Replace with:

```
\2
```

Explanation:

- `type(?!3\.)\d+` Match a type other than `3`
- `\.value(\d+)=` Match every thing up to `=` but capture digits
- `\K` Forget matches up to now
- `\d+` Match following digits
- `(?=` Start of positive lookahead

  - `[\s\S]*?` Match anything lazily
  - `type3\.value\1=` Up to the same value of `type3`
  - `(\d+)` Then capture its value in CP #2
- `)` End of positive lookahead

[Live demo](https://regex101.com/r/50QXfc/1)

The point is matching `valueX` from a `type` different than `3` then look for the same `valueX` from `type3`. If `valueX` is hypothetical or there isn't anything special to be looked, then there is no pure approach using regex in a find / replace functionality.

Comment: For Notepad++ use: (FzgF(?!84\.)\d{2})\.(\S+)=\S+(?=[\s\S]*?FzgF84\.\2=(\S+))  and substitution \1.\2=\3 since \K does not seem to work.

Comment: Notepad++ uses PCRE syntax and `\K` is documented in their docs. [Check it out](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions).