# How to search for a pattern only if it's the start of a word?

Tags: regex

Example: search for the pattern `man` but only as the beginning of a word (i.e. not preceded directly by letters).

This pattern would be found in the strings `man`, `spider-man`, `manpower`, `iron_man`. But not in `woman` or `human`.

Comment: `\b` is used to match the beginning or end of a word. However, it considers underscore to be part of a word.

Comment: If lookbehinds are supported: `(?<=[\W_]|^)man` otherwise: `(?:[\W_]|^)man`

Comment: Do you wish to match `"man"` in the strings `"_man"` and `"-man"`, or must the underscore or hyphen be preceded by a word?

Comment: anubhava and I have both asked quesions that you have seen. Why haven't you answered them?

Comment: Apologies for the delay. To be honest I didn't think of that case but it should not come up anyway. The solution below that does not match `-man` will work for my use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have assumed that if the word `"man"` is preceded by a hyphen or underscore, to achieve a match the hyphen or underscore must be preceded by a letter (e.g., `"-man"` would not be matched).

The `\K` escape sequence resets the beginning of the match to the current position in the token list. If supported by the regex engine, the following regular expression (with the case-indifferent flag set)  could be used.

```
(?:^| |[a-z][-_])\Kman
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GuNsWS/9/)

The selected answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950/support-of-k-in-regex) provides a list of regex engines that support `\K`. That list was last updated in August 2019.

The regex engine performs the following operations.

```
(?:       # begin non-capture group
  ^       # match beginning of line
  |       # or
          # match a space
  |       # or
  [a-z]   # match a letter
  [-_]    # match '-' or '_'
)         # end non-capture group
\K        # discard everything matched so far
man       # match 'man'
```

Alternatively, a capture group could be used.

```
(?:^| |[a-z][-_])(man)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/GuNsWS/10/)

Comment: This incorrecly doesn't match `lol man`.

Comment: @ruohola, thank you for the heads-up. I made a small change.

Comment: Thank you for the in depth explanation of the solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use positive lookbehind to achieve this:

```
(?<=^|[a-z][_-]|\s)man
```

[**regex101 demo**](https://regex101.com/r/DfuLUH/5)

[image: regex101 ss]

Comment: OK. So it does.

Comment: To return the favour, try `"12 mangos"`. Also you show that `"bad   man"` does not match when there is more than one space between "bad" and "man". Should it not?

Comment: @Swoveland `12 mangos` is a correct match, since `12 manpower` is also. They cannot be differenciated eith regex.

Comment: This works as well - thank you for the explanation and examples

Answer (score -1):

Add a word boundary `\b` or look behind for underscore to the start:

```
((?<=_)|\b)man
```

See [live demo](https://rubular.com/r/3d3vsIVxphOFoN).

Comment: This matches `-man`.

Comment: @ruohola so what?

Comment: OP specified in the commets that thst shouldn't match.

Comment: @ruohola where?

Comment: Last comment on his question.

Comment: @ruohola that comment was added a day after I posted this answer, which correctly matches (or doesn’t match)  everything asked for in the question, and as such perfectly answers the question as asked, and as still asked. To clarify, future visitors looking for an answer to this question can successfully use my answer.

Comment: Was just heads up, since you (obviously) hadn't seen the comment.