# Regex SSN and Tax ID combination

Tags: regex

I need a regex which can satisfy both SSN and Tax ID. It can take spaces or even hyphens.

Here are valid formats:

1. 12-3456789
2. 123456789
3. 123 45 6789
4. 123-45-6789

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation of the "valid" strings boils down to two distinct patterns which can use either `-`, a whitespace character, or nothing at all as a separator. This pattern ensures that when a separator is used more than once, it matches across both instances by using the `\k{}` token:

```
^\d{2}[-\s]?\d{7}$|\d{3}(?<sep>[-\s])\d{2}\k<sep>\d{4}
```

[<sup>Regex101</sup>](https://regex101.com/r/EWUHHF/2)

Be mindful that `\k` is only supported in [select RegExp engines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13543042/269970) (linked answer is slightly outdated, but still helpful starting point for research). I'll assume you're using a supported engine, as you haven't mentioned specifically what language/engine you're working with.

Comment: Esqew, I was in a rush to test the regex and did not read through your entire answer. I'm using javascript to test this regex and updating regex to escape "\k" breaks pattern for 123-456-7890 and123 456 7890 patterns. Is there an alternative?

Comment: @aspnetbeginner245 Did you happen to do any research on your own in order to solve the problem? It's [well documented that JavaScript supports the same `\k` token for backreferences](https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences). The only difference is that syntactically it's slightly different (`\k<sep>` vs. `\k{sep}`); see my updated [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/EWUHHF/2).

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this: `\d{2,3}[- ]?\d{2}[- ]?\d{4,5}`

Test it out here:
https://regex101.com/r/TJa5fE/2

Comment: I still don't think this meets OP's requirements, as it allows strings like `12 34-5678`, which wouldn't be valid in OPs spec.