# Linux extract text between specific strings

Tags: regex, linux, awk, sed, grep

I have multiple files with different job names. The job name is specified as follows.

`#SBATCH --job-name=01_job1           #Set the job name`

I want to use sed/awk/grep to automatically get the name, that is to say, what follows '--job-name=' and precedes the comment '#Set the job name'. For the example above, I want to get 01_job1. The job name could be longer for several files, and there are multiple = signs in following lines in the file.

I have tried using `grep -oP "job-name=\s+\K\w+" file` and get an empty output. I suspect that this doesn't work because there is no space between 'name=' and '01_job1', so they must be understood as a single word.

I also unsuccessfully tried using `awk '{for (I=1;I<NF;I++) if ($I == "name=") print $(I+1)}' file`, attempting to find the characters after 'name='.

Lastly, I also unsuccessfully tried `sed -e 's/name=\(.*\)#Set/\1/'` file to find the characters between 'name=' and the beginning of the comment '#Set'. I receive the whole file as my output when I attempt this.

I appreciate any guidance. Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Use this, you was close, just correctness of your `grep -oP` attempt (the main issue if you are trying to match a `space` after `=` character):

```
$ grep -oP -- '--job-name=\K\S+' file
01_job1
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `job-name=` | 'job-name=' |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [perlmonks look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\S+` | non-whitespace (all but \n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: For some reason I have to escape the dashes on Macos Terminal. `ggrep -oP '\--job-name=\K\S+'`. ggrep is just GNU grep.

Comment: No, check my edited POST with `--` _end of parameters_

Comment: What is the meaning of `"--"`

Comment: Check edited post again

Comment: That explains why I had to escape the pattern without double dahs. Everything makes sense now.

Answer (score 2):

You need to match the whole string with **sed** and capture just what you need to get, and use `-n` option with the `p` flag:

```bash
sed -n 's/.*name=\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p'
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/EczRuf):

```bash
#!/bin/bash
s='#SBATCH --job-name=01_job1           #Set the job name'
sed -n 's/.*name=\([^[:space:]]*\).*/\1/p' <<< "$s"
# => 01_job1
```

*Details*:

- `-n` - suppresses default line output
- `.*` - any text
- `name=` -  a literal `name=` string
- `\([^[:space:]]*\)` - Group 1 (`\1`): any zero or more chars other than whitespace
- `.*` - any text
- `p` - print the result of the successful substitution.

Comment: With `awk`, you [could probably use](https://ideone.com/qftmp6) `awk '$2 ~ /^--job-name=/ {gsub(/.*=/, "", $2); print $2}'`, but that depends on assumptions already.

Answer (score 2):

Simlar to the [answer of Gilles Quenot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75019706/8344060)

```
grep -oP -- '--job-name=\K.*(?= *# *Set the job name)'
```

This adds a look-ahead to ensure that the string is followed by `#Set the job name`

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** In GNU `awk` with your shown samples please try following `awk` code.

```bash
awk -v RS=' --job-name=\\S+' 'RT && split(RT,arr,"="){print arr[2]}' Input_file
```

***OR*** a non-one liner form of above GNU `awk` code would be:

```bash
awk -v RS=' --job-name=\\S+' '
RT && split(RT,arr,"="){
   print arr[2]
}
' Input_file
```

---

***2nd solution:*** Using any `awk` please try following code.

```bash
awk -F'[[:space:]]+|--job-name=' '{print $3}' Input_file
```

---

***3rd solution:*** Using GNU `grep` please try following code with your shown samples and using non-greedy `.*?` approach here in regex.

```bash
grep -oP '^.*?--job-name=\K\S+' Input_file
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lookbehind and lookahead with GNU grep to get exactly what you describe:

```
grep -oP '(?<=--job-name=)\S+(?=\s+#Set the job name)' file
```

Or with awk:

```
awk '/^#SBATCH[[:space:]]+--job-name=/ && 
     /#Set the job name$/ {
        sub(/^[^=]*=/,"")   
        sub(/#[^#]*$/,"")   
        print
     }' file
```

Or perl:

```
perl -lnE 'say $1 if /(?<=--job-name=)(\S+)(?=\s+#Set the job name)/'   file
```

Any prints:

```
01_job1
```