# How to use bash to get unique dates from list of file names

Tags: bash

I have a large number of file names. I need to create a bash script that gets all of the unique dates from the file names.

Example:

input:

```
opencomposition_dxxx_20201123.csv.gz     
opencomposition_dxxv_20201123.csv.gz
opencomposition_dxxu_20201123.csv.gz     
opencomposition_sxxv_20201123.csv.gz
opencomposition_sxxe_20211223.csv.gz 
opencomposition_sxxe_20211224.csv.gz  
opencomposition_sxxe_20211227.csv.gz  
opencomposition_sxxesgp_20230106.csv.gz
```

output:

```
20201123 20211224 20211227 20230106
```

Code:

```
for asof_dt in `find -H ./ -maxdepth 1 -nowarn -type f -name *open*.gz
| sort -r | cut -f3 -d "_" | cut -f1 -d"." | uniq`; do
    echo $asof_dt
done
```

Error:

```
line 20: /bin/find: Argument list too long
```

Comment: What is the problem with your code?

Comment: Do all the cutting first, then pipe to `sort -u`.

Comment: line 19: /bin/find: Argument list too long

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Like this (`GNU grep`):

You need to add quotes on the glob: `'*open*.gz'`, if not, the shell try to expand the wildcard `*`.

```
find -H ./ -maxdepth 1 -nowarn -type f -name '*open*.gz' |
    grep -oP '_\K\d{8}(?=\.csv)' |
    sort -u
```

### Output

```
20201123
20211223
20211224
20211227
20230106
```

### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `_` | _ |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [perlmonks look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\d{8}` | digits (0-9) (8 times) |
| `(?=` | [look ahead](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `\.` | . |
| `csv` | 'csv' |
| `)` | end of look-ahead |

Comment: I'm still getting line 20: /bin/find: Argument list too long

Comment: Check my edited answer, added quotes on the wildcard expansion

Answer (score 1):

Using `tr`:

```
find -H ./ -maxdepth 1 -nowarn -type f -name '*open*.gz' | tr -d 'a-z_.' | sort -u
```

Answer (score 0):

If filenames don't contain newline characters, a *quick-and-dirty* method, similar to your attempt, might be

```
printf '%s\n' open*.gz | cut -d_ -f3 | cut -d. -f1 | sort -u
```

Note that `printf` is a bash builtin command and `argument list too long` is not  applied to bash builtins.