# Look for pattern `{{ <anything inside> }}` in twig files (and deeper dirs) and output to a text file in a list

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I'm searching a directory (and deeper directories) for twig files that have variables `{{ something var name }}` and I would like to output into a file (twig-vars.txt).

Maybe using `grep` and `regex`? This is not my wheelhouse, so thanks in advance!

Example output (twig-vars.txt):

```
{{ somevar }}
{{ someothervar }}
{{ site.url }}
{{ ... }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### With `grep` in `PCRE` mode:

```
grep -oP '{{\s*\K[\w.]+' file
-------8<------------------
somevar
someothervar
site
```

##### Or with Perl:

```
perl -nE 'say $& if/{{\s*\K[\w.]+/' file
-------8<------------------
somevar
someothervar
site
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `{{` | '{{' |
| `\s*` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `[\w.]+` | any character of: word characters (a-z, A- Z, 0-9, _), '.' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

##### Or with `awk`

```
awk -F'{{ | }}' '{print $2}' file
-------8<------------------
somevar
someothervar
site.url
```

Comment: thx so much, but I'm getting `grep: invalid option -- P` -- I'm on a new Mac btw.  thoughts?

Comment: When I run these commands `awk` or `pearl` in the directory of the twig files, I don't get any output. "twig-vars.txt" 0L, 0B


touch file
awk -F'{{ | }}' '{print $2}' file


empty file.

Comment: Oh -- it would be something like `awk -F'{{ | }}' '{print $2}' * > twig-vars.txt`

Comment: One more thing -- This script isn't picking up `{{ site.url }}`. thoughts? I need `{{ <anything> }}` thanks btw!

Comment: @n8tron : better to escape the `{` and `}`, otherwise `gawk --posix` mode would act up : `echo '{{ somethingvar }}' | gawk -F'{{ | }}' --posix '{print $2}'` ::::::::  |> `gawk: fatal: invalid regexp: Invalid preceding regular expression: /{{ | }}/` :::::::::  `echo '{{ somethingvar }}' | gawk -F'[{][{] | [}][}]' --posix '{print $2}'` |> `somethingvar`