# How do I write regex to pull patch version out of semvar

Tags: regex

I'm trying to use regex to pull just the patch version out of some semvars in the form `v1.2.3`

I've got some regex which can match the `v1.2.` part however I'm struggling to get the other part, the `3` (which I actually want back)

I'm using `^v\d+\.\d+\.` to select the first part.

I'm trying to use a negative lookahead with this to then select everything after it with `(?!(v\d+\.\d+\.)).*` but this just seems to return everything after the `v` rather than everything after the group

Any pointers would be really appreciated, thanks!

Comment: How about this `v\d+\.\d+\.(\d+)`, https://regex101.com/r/HLPF3f/1

Comment: What is the tool or language?

Answer (score 1):

##### In this special case:

```
'^(?<=v\d\.\d\.)[[:alnum:]]+'
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | start of string |
| `(?<=` | [look behind](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) to see if there is: |
| `v` | v |
| `\d` | digits (0-9) |
| `\.` | . |
| `\d` | digits (0-9) |
| `\.` | . |
| `)` | end of look-behind |
| `[[:alnum:]]+` | any character of: letters and digits (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

##### A more generic solution than works with any length of digits

```
'^v\d+\.\d+\.\K.[[:alnum:]]+'
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | start of string |
| `v` | v |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\.` | . |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\.` | . |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `[[:alnum:]]+` | any character of: letters and digits (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

---

Check `man tr | grep -FA1 '[:'` for a `POSIX` character classes like `[[:alnum:]]`

Comment: Can the patch version be something else than a number? I mean something like `v2.10.a` instead of `v2.10.458` ? In any case, I would prefer not using `.*` at the end as it matches spaces or any other char which could not be a patch number. So I would replace `.*` by `\d+` or eventually `[\da-z]+`.