# Regex Find the value after a keyword and remove everything else including the keyword

Tags: regex

I am trying to read the value

```
Colli 182515612/OT 37/SA
```

The only value I'll need is `182515612`. Since there are multiple 9 digits numbers found in the file I need the regex to look for `Colli` and then just separate the 9 digit value after that from everything else.

I have tried `[^colli ](\d{9})` and `[colli ][0-9]{9}`
The second one seems to at least read out the value however it seems to just look for the numbers with an empty space in front of it, so it might read out other values as well.

Comment: Which tool/programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

##### This regex:

```
^Colli+\s+\K\b\d{9}
```

[online demo](https://regex101.com/r/xgLFub/1)

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `^` | the beginning of the string |
| `Colli` | Colli |
| `\s+` | whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `\b` | the boundary between a word char (\w) and something that is not a word char |
| `\d{9}` | digits (0-9) (9 times) |

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
(?<=Colli )\d{9}
```

[Regex demo.](https://regex101.com/r/kxHfwK/1)

---

This matches 9 digits that are preceded with string `"Colli "`