# grep output from file

Tags: file, grep

How to remove the ### from grep output?

File containing:

```
### Invoked at: Wed Dec  7 22:24:35 2022 ###
```

My grep command:

```
grep -oP "Invoked at: \K(.*)" $file
```

Expected output:

```
Wed Dec  7 22:24:35 2022
```

Current output:

```
Wed Dec  7 22:24:35 2022 ###
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
grep -oP "Invoked at: \K.*\d+" "$file"
```

(no need parenthesis).

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `Invoked at:` | 'Invoked at: ' |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=518444) and [Support of K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `.*` | any character except \n (0 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |
| `\d+` | digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Answer (score 0):

You can remove a character from an output by adding `| tr -d "#"`, so in your case this becomes:

```
grep -oP "Invoked at: \K(.*)" $file | tr -d "#"
```

Answer (score 0):

You could match the last digit before matching any character except `#`

```
grep -oP "\bInvoked at: \K[^#]*\d" $file
```

Output

```
Wed Dec  7 22:24:35 2022
```

The pattern matches:

- `\bInvoked at: \K` Match `Invoked at:`  and forget what is matched so far
- `[^#]*` Repeat 0+ times any char except `#`
- `\d` Match a digit

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WYdvc1/1)

Or a more specific match for the whole example string using a case insensitive match with `grep -oiP`

```
^###\h+Invoked\h+at:\h+\K[a-z]+\h+[a-z]+\h+\d\d?\h+\d\d?:\d\d?:\d\d?\h+\d{4}(?=\h+###$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uI5ErH/1)