# Grep a string from file and create variables from output in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have file in Linux like below.

```
20230512 12:42:06 INFO: job ID 
20230512 12:42:06 INFO: workflowID
20230512 12:42:06 INFO: {'jobsData': [{'jobID': '123_abc', 'jobStatus': 'RUNNING'}], 'timeoutData': {}, 'workflowID': 'bbc_999', 'workflowState': 'RUNNING'}
XXXX
YYY
ZZZ
```

Now from this file I want to find out the line where I have the string `jobID` is present.

I did like below

```
grep 'jobID' file_name
```

I get the below result

```
20230512 12:42:06 INFO: {'jobsData': [{'jobID': '123_abc', 'jobStatus': 'RUNNING'}], 'timeoutData': {}, 'workflowID': 'bbc_999', 'workflowState': 'RUNNING'}
```

Now from this I want to extract data for `jobID` and `workflowID` and store them as variables

```
jobID='123_abc'
workflowID='bbc_999'
```

How can I do that

Comment: @GillesQuénot That gets you the whole line, not just specific fields from it.

Comment: You can use `grep -o pattern` to output just the part of the line that matches the pattern, and assign that to a variable.

Comment: @Barmar It is only giving me values like `jobID` or `workflowId`. I want the value after `:` from that line as variable

Comment: Then you didn't use the correct pattern, it has to match the value after `:`. E.g. `'jobID': '[^']*'`

Comment: What is generating this weird output? Can you change the behavior to have a proper JSON?

Comment: If you're using GNU grep you can use the `-P` option and then use a lookbehind, so that `jobID` won't be included in the result.

Comment: @Barmar I did like `abc = grep -o 'jobID' file_name` when I `echo $abc` the output is `jobID`

Comment: Since your pattern is only `jobID`, of course that's all that it returns. The pattern has to include the part of the line you want. `grep` can't guess that you want something after it.

Comment: `sed -En '/jobID/ s/.{24}//p' file | tr "'" "\"" | jq -r '.jobsData | .[].jobID'`?

Comment: It sounds like you may need to read a tutorial on regular expressions if this is confusing you.

Comment: Not very reliable Cyrus IMHO

Comment: @GillesQuénot: This might be more reliable with GNU awk: `awk -v FPAT="'[^']+'" '/jobID/{$1=$1; print $3}' file`

Comment: I agree, will be far better and smart.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `grep` you can get the results like below. `sort` is used to remove duplicates from output

```
job_id =$(grep -o 'jobID.*' file_name | cut -f2- -d: | cut -d ',' -f 1  | sort -u)
echo "$job_id"

workflow_id=$(grep -o 'workflowID.*' file_name | cut -f2- -d: | cut -d ',' -f 1 | sort -u )
echo "$workflow_id"
```

Answer (score 2):

With `GNU` `grep` in `PCRE` mode:

```
read jobid workflowid < <(grep -oP '(?:jobID|workflowID)\047: \047\K[^\047]+' file)
echo "$jobid"
echo "$workid"
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `(?:` | group, but do not capture: |
| `jobID` | 'jobID' |
| `|` | OR |
| `workflowID` | 'workflowID' |
| `)` | end of grouping |
| `\047` | single quote in octal |
| `:` | ': ' |
| `\047` | single quote in octal |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) and [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `[^\047]+` | any character except: ' (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

---

`>(command ...)` or `<(...)` is replaced by a temporary filename. Writing or reading that file causes bytes to get piped to the command inside. Often used in combination with file redirection: `cmd1 2> >(cmd2)`.

See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ProcessSubstitution
and
http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/024

Answer (score 2):

If `awk` is an option, you may be able to use command substitution to extract the values you need:

```
jobID=$(awk '/jobID/{gsub(/,|\047/,""); print $6}' src.file)
workflowID=$(awk '/jobID/{gsub(/,|\047/,""); print $12}' src.file)
```

Output:

```
echo "$jobID"
123_abc
echo "$workflowID"
bbc_999
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$ jobID=$(awk -F'INFO:' '/jobsData/{gsub(/\047/,"\""); print $NF}' file|jq -r '.jobsData[0].jobID')
$ workflowID=$(awk -F'INFO:' '/jobsData/{gsub(/\047/,"\""); print $NF}' file|jq -r '.workflowID')

$ echo "$jobID" 
123_abc

$ echo "$workflowID"
bbc_999
```

Using bash array

```
$ declare -A array="($(awk -F'INFO:' '/jobsData/{gsub(/\047/,"\""); print $NF}' file|jq -r '. | "[workflowID]=\(.workflowID) [jobID]=\(.jobsData[0].jobID)"'))"
$ declare -p array 
declare -A array=([jobID]="123_abc" [workflowID]="bbc_999" )

$ echo "${array[workflowID]}"
bbc_999

$ echo "${array[jobID]}"
123_abc
```

Answer (score 2):

Using GNU awk and bash associative arrays:

```
$ declare -A arr="( $(awk -v RS="'[^']+'[ :]+'[^']*'" -F"'" '{$0=RT} NF==5{print "["$2"]=\047"$4"\047"}' file) )"
```

you get an array of all the `'name': 'value'` pairs from the input:

```
$ declare -p arr
declare -A arr=([workflowID]="bbc_999" [jobStatus]="RUNNING" [jobID]="123_abc" [workflowState]="RUNNING" )
```

You can then set scalar variables from the array if you like:

```
$ jobID="${arr[jobID]}"
$ echo "$jobID"
123_abc
```

but you don't have to.