# How to grep my one-line file with constant key?

Tags: linux, grep

This is my file

```
__version__="1.11.10"
```

numerical part will change all the time and I want to grep this.

```
new_tag=`grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+'_version.py`
```

failed.
how to extract 1.11.10 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use `sed`:

```bash
sed -n 's/.*="\([^"]*\)"/\1/p' file
```

To assign to a variable:

```bash
new_tag=$(sed -n 's/.*="\([^"]*\)"/\1/p' file)
```

See the [online Bash demo](https://ideone.com/fs6AtN).

*Details*

- `-n` - suppresses default line output in the `sed` command
- `.*="\([^"]*\)"` - a POSIX BRE pattern that matches

  - `.*` - any text then
  - `="` - a `="` string
  - `\([^"]*\)` - capturing group #1 that captures zero or more chars other than `"`
  - `"` - a `"` char
- `\1` - replaces the match with Group 1 contents
- `p` - `p`rints the resulting value

Answer (score 1):

What I would do:

```
grep -oP '__version__="\K[^"]+'
```

---

- `-o` display only the matched part
- `-P` allow PCRE regexes

---

The backquote is used in the old-style command substitution. The `foo=$(command)` syntax is recommended instead. Backslash handling inside `$()` is less surprising, and `$()` is easier to nest. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082

So use:

```
variable=$(grep ....)
```

##### The regular expression matches as follows:

| Node | Explanation |
| --- | --- |
| `__version__="` | as is |
| `\K` | resets the start of the match (what is `K`ept) as a shorter alternative to using a look-behind assertion: [look arounds](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#Lookaround-Assertions) and [Support of \K in regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13542950) |
| `[^"]+` | any character except: `"` (1 or more times (matching the most amount possible)) |

Comment: As the file contains only one line, is this simpler :  `grep -oP '"\K[^"]+'`

Answer (score 1):

The regex for you expected value works, but you should update the syntax to using a sub shell:

```
new_tag=$(grep -Eo '[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+' file)
```

Or as an alternative using `gnu awk` matching the string with a capture group, and then print the capture group 1 value:

```
new_tag=$(awk 'match($0, /__version__="([0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+)"/, a){print a[1]}' file)
```