# C# Regular expression search gives false

Tags: c#, regex, search, text-search

I am trying to do a program that searches for certain tags inside textfiles and see if there is text in between those tags. Example of tags below.

```
--<UsrDef_Mod_Trigger_repl_BeginMod>
--<UsrDef_Mod_Trigger_repl_EndMod>
```

So i want to search for `--<UsrDef_Mod_` and `_Begin` or `_End`

I made these RegExp, but i get false on every single one.

```
if (Regex.Match(line, @"/--<UsrDef_Mod_.*_BeginMod>/g", RegexOptions.None).Success)
else if (Regex.Match(line, @"/--<UsrDef_Mod_.*_EndMod>/g", RegexOptions.None).Success)
```

So any help to find where im going wrong. I have used regexr.com to check my regexp and its getting a match there but not in C#.

Comment: you can just try out yourself, e.g. here: http://regexstorm.net/tester. BTW Instead of Regex.Match(...).Success you may as well use Regex.IsMatch

Comment: not trying to avoid the problem here, but a possible solution would be:    line.substring(line.indexOf("--<UsrDef_Mod_")+14,line.indexOf("_Begin")-1);  this will get you what is between both hardcoded strings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The .NET library Regex doesn't understand the `"/ /g"`wrapper.

Just remove it:

```
// Regex.Match(line, @"/--<UsrDef_Mod_.*_BeginMod>/g", 
   Regex.Match(line, @"--<UsrDef_Mod_.*_BeginMod>",
```

Comment: I just realized this myself by using the regexstorm.net/tester. After trying everything i removed them for the heck of it and it worked.. but thx.

Answer (score 2):

```
if (Regex.Match(line, @"--<UsrDef_Mod_.*_BeginMod>", RegexOptions.None).Success)
if (Regex.Match(line, @"--<UsrDef_Mod_.*_EndMod>", RegexOptions.None).Success)
```

Those both get a match - you just remove the /-- and /g options - 
As per Henk Holtermann´s Answer - [a comparison of perl and c# regex options on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3417644/translate-perl-regular-expressions-to-net) - for further reference.

Comment: The `/` delimiters should definitely not be used.

Answer (score 0):

```
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"<UsrDef_Mod_([a-zA-Z_]+)_BeginMod>([\s\S]+?)<UsrDef_Mod_\1_EndMod>");
if (matches != null)
    foreach (Match m in matches)
        Console.WriteLine(m.Groups[2].Value);
```

Group #2 will contain the text inside two tags.