# String.Empty versus ""

Tags: c#

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the difference between String.Empty and “”](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and)

How is `String.Empty` different from `""`?

Comment: If you open it in reflector you will see they are the same

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/151472/what-is-the-difference-between-string-empty-and/151481

Comment: The popular related question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or

Answer (score 117, accepted):

It's not different.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.empty.aspx:

> The value of this field is the zero-length string, "".
>
> In application code, this field is most commonly used in assignments to initialize a string variable to an empty string. To test whether the value of a string is either `null` or `String.Empty`, use the `IsNullOrEmpty` method.

Comment: As the duplicate say, its not different in .NET 2 and above.

Comment: In the .NET 1 era, it was different. So, you'll see String.Empty in old code that is still in use, and reflexively entered by old-schoolers who suffered through the .NET 1 era. Be kind; it left a mark.

Answer (score 117):

According to [Brad Abrams](https://web.archive.org/web/20151012072501/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/brada/archive/2003/04/22/49997.aspx):

> As David implies, there difference
> between String.Empty and “” are pretty
> small, but there is a difference.  “”
> actually creates an object, it will
> likely be pulled out of the string
> intern pool, but still… while
> String.Empty creates no object… so if
> you are really looking for ultimately
> in memory efficiency, I suggest
> String.Empty.  However, you should
> keep in mind the difference is so
> trival you will like never see it in
> your code...
>
> As for System.String.Empty or
> string.Empty or String.Empty… my care
> level is low ;-)

**Update (6/3/2015):**

It has been mentioned in the comments that the above quote from 2003 is no longer true (I assume this is referring to the statement that `""` actually creates an object).  So I just created a couple of simple console programs in C# 5 (VS 2013):

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Outputs "True"
        Debug.WriteLine(string.IsInterned(string.Empty) != null);
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        // Outputs "True"
        Debug.WriteLine(string.IsInterned("") != null);
    }
}
```

This demonstrates that both `""` and `String.Empty` are both interned when your code starts running, meaning that for all practical purposes they are the same..

The most important part of Brad's comment is this:

> you should keep in mind the difference is so trival you will
> like never see it in your code...

That's the bottom line.  Choosing between "" and String.Empty is not a performance-based decision.  [Don't waste a lot of time thinking about it.](https://blog.codinghorror.com/micro-optimization-and-meatballs/)  Choose based on whatever you find more readable, or whatever convention is already being used in your project.

Comment: It is a lot faster to type two quotes than String.Empty. Two quotes is cross platform. It's a no brainer.

Comment: I for one find `""` much easier to read and understand than `string.Empty`.

Comment: I've had numerous cases while quickly prototyping code, I littered `""` all over the place, which later introduced many bugs, because *intent* was not clear: "Did I mean to say: pass empty string here, intentionally" or "Did I forgot to pass a non-empty string here".

Comment: @GeorgeChakhidze you don't *need* string.Empty for that, as you could also introduce a single letter constant for the empty string while prototyping

Answer (score 15):

There is no difference.  Some prefer to use `String.Empty` for code readability purposes.  Use the one you are comfortable with using.

Comment: In my opinion, String.Empty is not easier to read. I don't like it. I always use "". We use double quotes for non-empty string literals, so to be consistent we should double quotes for string literals too.

Answer (score 11):

For the most part `String.Empty is identical to ""` however usually I find its easier to use `String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)` instead of having to compare `str == "" || str == null` Also if you are on .NET 4.0 `String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(str)` covers even more cases, and is by far the best.

Comment: You miss the point:
`String.IsNullOrEmpty(str)`has nothing to do with `string.Empty`, except that the word empty appear in both places.

Comment: `str == "" || str == null` looks quite ineffective to me, given that the left side is evaluated first. Just another reason to use the `IsNullOrEmpty` method :-)

Answer (score 4):

**string.Empty** is always the same object

**""** is always a new object, which may have to be removed by the garbage collector.

**Therefore you should always use string.empty instead of "".**

```
string a="";
string b=string.Empty;
```

is translate to

```
IL_0000:  ldstr       ""
IL_0005:  ldsfld      System.String.Empty
```

Comment: A new object is not created every time. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning

Comment: The compiler will "link" them all to an empty string.

Comment: I read somewhere (sorry, I don't remember where) that the empty string is duplicated once in each assembly. So each assembly that uses `""` instead of `System.String.Empty` is wasting *valuable memory*! ;-)

Comment: Did you mean "The main reason for NOT using String.Empty is readability"?

Comment: Rehashing an old thread just for fun:  This answer was once true, but not anymore.  Rest In Peace