# How can I get all Labels on a form and set the Text property of those with a particular name pattern to string.empty?

Tags: c#, winforms, generics, dynamic, lambda

I want to clear all values on a form where the control is a label and its name starts with "label"

This code:

```
List<Label> lbls = this.Controls.OfType<Label>().ToList();
foreach (var lbl in lbls)
{
    if (lbl.Name.StartsWith("label"))
    {
        lbl.Text = string.Empty;
    }
}
```

...doesn't work, because the lambda is finding nothing - lbls.Count = 0.

Wouldn't this get ALL the controls on the form, even those that are children of other controls (such as, in my case, Panels)?

Comment: No, it does only find controls in the parent container. But i assume that you know what you want to find. So you just have to specify the container(s) you want to search. You can use `Concat` to add all labels.

Comment: I don't think this will search all the containers recursively

Comment: No, this.Controls contains only the first level of controls. Those directly hosted on the Form surface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use this method:

```
public void ClearLabel(Control control)
{
   if (control is Label)
   {
       Label lbl = (Label)control;
       if (lbl.Text.StartsWith("label"))
           lbl.Text = String.Empty;

   }
   else
       foreach (Control child in control.Controls)
       {
           ClearLabel(child);
       }

}
```

You just need to pass form to ClearLabel method.

Comment: I had to change the lbl.Text.StartsWith() to lbl.Name.StartsWith(), but close enough.

Answer (score 4):

No, it will not recursively search Panels.

To do what you want, you can do:

```
void changeLabel(Control c)
{
    if (lbl.Name.StartsWith("label"))
    {
        lbl.Text = string.Empty;
    }

    foreach(Control _c in c.Controls)
        changeLabel(_c);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This does not touch the matter of recursion brought up in the previous answers; it's just another, a little more succint way of expressing what you had:

```
var labels = Controls.OfType<Label>().Where( x => x.Name.StartsWith("label") );
foreach (var label in labels)
{
    label.Text = "";
}
```

That's what I ended up writing, I thought of adding it here just for completeness - essentially, you don't need `ToList()`, and [`String.Empty` hasn't had any advantage over `""` for ages.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2905378/3258851)