# How to visible label with other name in c#

Tags: c#

I have labels and their name like label1,label2,... etc. and I know how to visible label like `label1.visible = true` But what I want to do is make some of them visible with other name like the code below

```
            for (i = 0; i < ceksayisi*2; i++)
            {
                num = i;
                labelname = "label" + num;
                labelname.visible = true;
            }
```

The code gives me `'string' does not contain a definition for 'visible' and no extension method 'visible' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`

Comment: Is this with ASP.NET ?

Comment: or even c#?....

Comment: If ASP.NET, `(Label)Page.FindControl("label" + num)` should work

Comment: It is important to state the GUI framework you are using: ASP.NET, Windows Forms, WPF, etc.

Comment: If you are using Windows Forms, check this:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12808943/how-can-i-get-all-labels-on-a-form-and-set-the-text-property-of-those-with-a-par/12809043

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since that is a case-sensitive programming language, it won't work with `labelname.visible = true;` but you have to change that piece of code with: `labelname.Visible = true;`

Edit:

Might have misunderstood, if you're trying to Show/Hide a label that you don't know the name dynamically, you may try doing something like this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ceksayisi*2; i++)
{
    num = i;
    Label labelname = (Label) Controls.Find("label" + num, true).FirstOrDefault();
    labelname.Visible = true;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Might I have the pleasure to know why my answer got downvoted? I don't think I can improve my skills if you won't tell me what I wrote wrong.

Comment: it fix my problem

Answer (score 0):

You are doing a classical mistake here. The Droid you are looking for are arrays and other collections. You can not build variable names like that outside of some really weakly typed langauges.

No .NET Langauge is weakly typed. And that is by design.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this You should use Dictionary here.

```
Dictionary<string, Label> keyValuePairs = new Dictionary<string, Label>();
```

And add your label in the dictionary with according keys

```
keyValuePairs.Add("label_" + num, label1);
```

you can access your labels like

```
Label lbl = keyValuePairs["label" + num];
```

then you can play with this lbl

```
lbl.Visible = false;
```