# Do you have to initialize a string variable inside a method?

Tags: c#, variables, unassigned-variable

I am programming in C# and I keep getting an error for my string variable `result`.

When I hover over the line `return result` it says use of unassigned local variable.

Do I have to assign result a value before I use it? How come i do not get the same error for `SqlDataReader` reader?

```
string searchbyLastName(string lastname)
{
    string result; 

    SqlDataReader reader;

    try
    {
        reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                if (reader["LastName"].ToString() == lastname)
                {
                    result = reader.GetString(0);
                    break;
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
        else 
           return "No results found";
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return("Database Error");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
if (reader["LastName"].ToString() == lastname)
```

If that is never true then `result` is not initialized.  The `SqlDataReader` is always initialized prior to being used.  Just initialize the string.

```
var result = "";
```

Comment: Bad practice. Use  var result = String.Empty;

Comment: @DanHunex: No thank you, please explain why you consider it a "bad practice".  There hasn't been any actual semantic difference in quite some time due to string interning.  Do you simply enjoy typing?

Comment: Why do you think String.IsNullOrWhitespace is added? Because people sometimes write " " instead of "" . But String.Empty always guarantee that it is empty

Comment: @DanHunex: They do?  Weird.  I have never, in over a decade of work, seen that error.  I think I'll stick with `""`, thanks though.  PS: `IsNullOrWhitespace` was almost certainly *not* added to account for typos when attempting to initialize a variable to an empty string.  It's meant to check for empty *input*, not incorrectly initialized variables.

Comment: Well, you can also see this but i m not trying to convince you with more than 10 years of experience http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2905378/string-empty-versus

Comment: @DanHunex: Well... the highest voted question there says pretty directly "there is no difference", but that's a technical answer.  How about this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/263191/in-c-should-i-use-string-empty-or-string-empty-or.  I agree with Jon Skeet there; you're inventing a problem.  If you like it, that's fine, I have nothing against it, but I prefer `""`, and I have never heard of someone typing `" "` which led to a bug.  Ever.  Of course, that doesn't mean it hasn't or will not happen, but I'll take my chances on this one.

Comment: @DanHunex: And I didn't mean to say that my ten years is some awesome accomplishment, but it's certainly a large enough sample size to have written many thousands of `""`'s

Answer (score 0):

The *compiler* needs to know you have definitely assigned a value to a variable, at the point where you are *using* that value.

In your case `reader` is always assigned a value (`reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();`), but `result` isn't, because that depends on `reader["LastName"].ToString() == lastname` being true, which may never happen (even if you designed the system so that in reality you always find a match - the compiler doen't know that).

So somewhere before you enter that while-loop you have to assign a value. `result = null` would be enough. This value could also be used to signal a "lastname not found" condition to the calling code.